# I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions

Tags: plotting

I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions.  Not a force field (short arrows) but continuous field lines that start on the charge.

Comment: I think he's looking for a 3D version of StreamPlot.

Comment: @David I was just coming to the same conclusion.  That's a good question. (+1)

Comment: @David seems so.

Comment: Michael Trott gives some [code for visualizing field lines of charges](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Do1Opir9guIC&pg=PA481) in his book. I can transcribe it if needed.

Comment: Hello Rainforest Frog and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. Don't forget to upvote good answers (and other people's questions) using the triangle above the number next to the post, and use the checkmark to "accept" the answer to your question that you think best answers it. You now have enough "reputation" (points) to visit the chat room and chat if you would like.

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for the nice comment!

Answer (score 47):

This is something I have used for my classes. Over time, I've tried to make it more and more user friendly, but that's also made it a little longish. I'll post the complete set of functions, with apologies if it's a bit unwieldy...

As you'll see, I found it does indeed work better in my use cases if I normalize the field, so that we advance along the field lines in more balanced steps. The hardest part in applying these functions is to choose the appropriate seed points.

```
fieldSolve::usage = 
  "fieldSolve[f,x,x0,\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(max\)]\)] \
symbolically takes a vector field f with respect to the vector \
variable x, and then finds a vector curve r[t] starting at the point \
x0 satisfying the equation dr/dt=\[Alpha] f[r[t]] for \
t=0...\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(max\)]\). Here \[Alpha]=1/|f[r[t]]| \
for normalization. To get verbose output add debug=True to the \
parameter list.";

fieldSolve[field_, varlist_, xi0_, tmax_, debug_: False] := Module[
  {xiVec, equationSet, t},
  If[Length[varlist] != Length[xi0], 
   Print["Number of variables must equal number of initial conditions\
\nUSAGE:\n" <> fieldSolve::usage]; Abort[]];
  xiVec = Through[varlist[t]];
  (* Below, Simplify[equationSet] would cost extra time 
    and doesn't help with the numerical solution, so   don't try to simplify. *)

  equationSet = Join[
    Thread[
     Map[D[#, t] &, xiVec] == 
      Normalize[field /. Thread[varlist -> xiVec]]
     ],
    Thread[
     (xiVec /. t -> 0) == xi0
     ]
    ];
  If[debug, 
   Print[Row[{"Numerically solving the system of equations\n\n", 
      TraditionalForm[(Simplify[equationSet] /. t -> "t") // 
        TableForm]}]]];
  (* This is where the differential equation is solved. 
  The Quiet[] command suppresses warning messages because numerical precision isn't crucial for our plotting purposes: *)

  Map[Head, First[xiVec /.
     Quiet[NDSolve[
       equationSet,
       xiVec,
       {t, 0, tmax}
       ]]], 2]
  ]   

fieldLinePlot[field_, varList_, seedList_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   Module[{sols, localVars, var, localField, plotOptions, 
    tubeFunction, tubePlotStyle, postProcess = {}}, 
   plotOptions = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot3D]];
   tubeFunction = OptionValue["TubeFunction"];
   If[tubeFunction =!= None,
    tubePlotStyle = Cases[OptionValue[PlotStyle], Except[_Tube]];
    plotOptions = 
     FilterRules[plotOptions, 
      Except[{PlotStyle, ColorFunction, ColorFunctionScaling}]];
    postProcess = 
     Line[x_] :> 
      Join[tubePlotStyle, {CapForm["Butt"], 
        Tube[x, tubeFunction @@@ x]}]
    ];
   If[Length[seedList[[1, 1]]] != Length[varList], 
    Print["Number of variables must equal number of initial \
conditions\nUSAGE:\n" <> fieldLinePlot::usage]; Abort[]];
   localVars = Array[var, Length[varList]];
   localField = 
    ReleaseHold[
     Hold[field] /. 
      Thread[Map[HoldPattern, Unevaluated[varList]] -> localVars]];
   (*Assume that each element of seedList specifies a point AND the \
length of the field line:*)Show[
    ParallelTable[
     ParametricPlot3D[
         Evaluate[
          Through[#[t]]], {t, #[[1, 1, 1, 1]], #[[1, 1, 1, 2]]}, 
         Evaluate@Apply[Sequence, plotOptions]
         ] &[fieldSolve[
        localField, localVars, seedList[[i, 1]], seedList[[i, 2]]
        ]
       ] /. postProcess, {i, Length[seedList]}
     ]
    ]
   ];

Options[fieldLinePlot] = 
  Append[Options[ParametricPlot3D], "TubeFunction" -> None];

SyntaxInformation[fieldLinePlot] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {2, 2}}, 
   "ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _, OptionsPattern[]}};

SetAttributes[fieldSolve, HoldAll];
```

The main function is `fieldLinePlot`, but I split it into two functions to be more modular. Also, the problem of where to start drawing the field lines is treated separately because it depends a lot on the particular application.

`fieldSolve[f,x,x0,Subscript[t, max]]` symbolically takes a vector field f with respect to the vector variable `x`, and then finds a vector curve `r[t]` starting at the point `x0` satisfying the equation `dr/dt = α f[r[t]]` for `t=0...tmax`. Here `α = 1/|f[r[t]]|` for normalization. To get verbose output add `debug=True` to the parameter list.

`fieldLinePlot[field,varlist,seedList]` plots 3D field lines of a vector field (first argument) that depends on the symbolic variables in `varlist`. The starting points for these variables are provided in seedList.

Each element of `seedList={{p1, T1},{p2, T2}...}` is a tuple where pi is the starting point of the $i^\mathrm{th}$ field line and `Ti` is the length of that field line in both directions from `Pi`.

Here are some examples:

#### 1) Coulomb field of two opposite charges at $\vec{r} = \vec{0}$ and $\vec{r} = (1, 1, 1)$:

Look at the form of `seedList` to see how the field line starting points and lengths are specified.

```
seedList = 
  With[{vertices = .1 N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1, 1]]]}, 
   Join[Map[{#, 2} &, vertices], 
    Map[{# + {1, 1, 1}, -2} &, vertices]]];

Show[fieldLinePlot[{x, y, z}/
    Norm[{x, y, z}]^3 - ({x, y, z} - {1, 1, 1})/
    Norm[{x, y, z} - {1, 1, 1}]^3, {x, y, z}, seedList, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 16], Tube[.01]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None], 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image]

#### 2) Magnetic field of an infinite straight wire:

```
With[{seedList = Table[{{x, 0, 0}, 6.5}, {x, .1, 1, .1}]
  },
 Show[fieldLinePlot[{-y, x, 0}/(x^2 + y^2), {x, y, z}, 
   seedList, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 16], Tube[.01]},
    PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None], 
  Graphics3D@Tube[{{0, 0, -.5}, {0, 0, .5}}], Background -> Black]]
```

[image]

---

**Edit: added variable line thickness to represent field strength**

The field lines can be given a color that scales with the field strength (the norm of the vector field along the lines), by specifying a `ColorFunction` in `fieldLinePlot`. For example, if the vector field has been defined as a function `f2` of variables `x,y,z`, then you could add the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[{x,y,z,u}, Quiet@Hue[Clip[ Norm[f2[x,y,z]],{0,20}]/20]]` as I mention in the comment section.

In this new edit, I added the ability to encode the field strength in the **thickness** of the field lines instead. This required adding a new option `"TubeFunction"` which works similarly to `ColorFunction`. It is a function of the three coordinates `x,y,z` and returns the radius of the **tube** representing the field line at that point. To calculate this radius in the examples below, I take the (unscaled) value of the field and get its `Norm`. Then I scale and constrain it to a reasonable range so that the thickness variations of the field lines don't look too grotesque:

#### 3) Same Coulomb field as above, but with varying field line *thickness*

```
f2[x_, y_,z_] := {x, y, z}/Norm[{x, y, z}]^3 - ({x, y, z} - {1, 1, 1})/
   Norm[{x, y, z} - {1, 1, 1}]^3

seedList = 
  With[{vertices = .1 N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1, 1]]]}, 
   Join[Map[{#, 2} &, vertices], 
    Map[{# + {1, 1, 1}, -2} &, vertices]]];

fieldLinePlot[f2[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, seedList, 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 16]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
 "TubeFunction" -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Quiet[Clip[Norm[f2[x, y, z]], {2, 40}]/200]], 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image: Coulomb varying thickness]

#### 4) Same magnetic field as above, this time with varying line thickness

```
f3[x_, y_, z_] := {-y, x, 0}/(x^2 + y^2)

With[{seedList = Table[{{x, 0, 0}, 6.5}, {x, .1, 1, .1}]}, 
 Show[fieldLinePlot[f3[x, y, z], {x, y, z}, seedList, 
   PlotStyle -> {Cyan, Specularity[White, 16]}, PlotRange -> All, 
   Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
   "TubeFunction" -> 
    Function[{x, y, z}, Quiet[Clip[Norm[f3[x, y, z]], {1, 40}]/200]]],
   Graphics3D@Tube[{{0, 0, -.5}, {0, 0, .5}}], Background -> Black]]
```

[image: Magnetic varying thickness]

Comment: BTW, is there any simple way to change thickness of the tube depending on field strength?

Comment: @Ruslan That would take some modifications. But you can already display the field strength by using colors, without any modifications to the current code. Just use it with some additional options. E.g., for the Coulomb field, define it as a function `f2[x_,y_,z]` and then add this to the `fieldLinePlot`:  `ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[{x,y,z,u}, Quiet@Hue[Clip[ Norm[f2[x,y,z]],{0,20}]/20]]` The factor `20` determines the cutoff for coloring near singularities. If the *thickness* were used for field strength, it would look *very thick* near the charges...

Comment: Of course, I meant that the thickness would have a maximum like clipping does in your color suggestion.

Comment: As for the colouring, I think more understandable would be to use `GrayLevel[1-#]&` instead of `Hue`.

Comment: @Ruslan Sure, that's up to anyone's taste. I may have time to do some modifications regarding thickness later... it's doable but not straightforward, unfortunately. The `Tube` command lets you adjust the thickness along the curve, but `ParametricPlot` (which I rely on) doesn't utilize that capability (for 1D curves).

Comment: @Ruslan I've edited the code so it can now do line thickness variations.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great. But for some reason it uses a huge amount of RAM and goes into heavy swapping on my machine with 4G of RAM.

Comment: @Ruslan I tried to be as efficient as possible in terms of graphics, so I would blame the rest on *Mathematica* - in terms of efficiency and speed, it can't compete with dedicated 3D visualization software. However, one can always build complex 3D scenes in *Mathematica* by doing it in smaller chunks and combining them with `Show` later. You could try that by doing chunks with smaller lists of seed points and combining them only at the end. As in: `seedList[[1;;5]]`, `seedList[[6;;10]]`, etc. for the argument of `fieldLinePlot`.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that the motion of the particle is governed by some force field, you could use `NDSolve` together with `ParametricPlot3D` to plot the individual field lines. For example, consider the force field

```
force[p_] := ({1, 1, 1} - p)/Norm[{1, 1, 1} - p]^3 - p/Norm[p]^3
```

The equations of motion are given by

```
p[t_] := {p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]}
eqs := Thread[p''[t] == force[p[t]]]
```

We also need some initial conditions, for example

```
ic := {Thread[p[0] == {1, 0, 0}], Thread[p'[0] == {0, 1, 0}]}
```

The system can then be solved according to

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqs, ic}, {p1, p2, p3}, {t, 0, 20}]
```

And the plot of this solution looks like

```
ParametricPlot3D[p[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want several field lines, you would need to rerun `NDSolve` for a list of initial conditions.

**Edit**

As rcollyer pointed out, this doesn't actually plot the field lines. For that you would need to solve `p'[t] == force[p[t]]/Norm[force[p[t]]` for which you can still use the method above, e.g.

```
eq := Thread[p'[t] == -force[p[t]]/Sqrt[force[p[t]].force[p[t]]]]
(* seeds for field lines *)
seeds = Flatten[{0.1 #, 0.1 # + {1, 1, 1}} & /@ 
   N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1, 1]]], 1];
sol = NDSolve[{eq, Thread[p[0] == #]}, {p1, p2, p3}, {t, 0, 40}][[1]] & /@ seeds;

ParametricPlot3D[p[s] /. sol, {s, 0, 20}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You can get the coordinates of the polyhedron easier (and more readable) by using the built-in parameter `VertexCoordinates` (`... /@ PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "VertexCoordinates"] ...`).

Comment: One more thing, the field lines are the integral curves of the vector field, i.e. solutions of $p'(t) = X(p(t))$, there is no division by a norm. (This equation holds on any differentiable manifold, and most of them don't even have a norm.)

Answer (score 13):

The closest thing [in the help files](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html#143100797) that I can see is this example. It might be of some use.

```
stackPlots[plots2D : {__Graphics},
  dh_, o : OptionsPattern[Graphics3D]] := Graphics3D[
  MapIndexed[
   Function[{g, index}, g[[1]] /. Arrow[v2d_] :> Arrow[v2d /.
        {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y, dh index[[1]]}]], 
   plots2D], o]

plotSpacing = 5;

values = {-1, 0, 1};
plots = MapIndexed[
  Function[{\[Lambda], i}, 
   StreamPlot[{y, \[Lambda] - x^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> 16, StreamScale -> 0.07,
    StreamStyle -> ColorData["SolarColors"][0.3 i[[1]]]]], values]

stackPlots[plots, plotSpacing, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic,
   MapIndexed[{plotSpacing #2[[1]], Row[{"\[Lambda] = ", #1}]} &, 
    values]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]