# Animating the Lorenz Equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, animation, version-8

I am trying to use the `Animate` command to vary a parameter of the Lorenz Equations in 3-D phase space and I'm not having much luck.

The equations are:

> $\begin{align*}
> \dot{x} &= \sigma(y-x)\\
> \dot{y} &= rx-y-xz\\
> \dot{z} &= xy-bz
> \end{align*}$

Where $\sigma, r, b > 0$ are parameters to be varied.

Insofar, I am using the `NDSolve` command to numerically integrate these equations, then `ParametricPlot3D` and the `Evaluate` command to plot them.

Just for starters, I am trying to create an animate command to vary $\sigma$ for example from 0 to 10. Can anyone guide me in the right direction? My code looks like this so far:

---

```
σ = 10;

NDSolve[{x'[t] == σ (y[t] - x[t]), 
         y'[t] == 28 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 8/3 z[t], 
         x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 25}]

Animate[ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. solution], {t, 0, 25}], {σ, 0, 25},
  AnimationRunning -> False]
```

---

This will generate an animated plot but obviously as `σ` varies, nothing is changing since I am not implementing new `NDSolve` commands. Can anyone guide me as to how I can implement successive `NDSolve`'s inside the animate command? Thank you

EDIT: I am using $r=28$ and $b=\frac83$ in place of `r` and `b` in my code.

Comment: Have a look at `ParametricNDSolveValue`.

Comment: Can I apply ParametricNDSolveValue or ParametricNDSolve to animations in 3D?

Comment: Yes, please give it a try.

Comment: I don't think my version of mathematica actually has those functions in them Lol.. I have mathematica 8.0, are these 9.0 commands?

Comment: Indeed, they are new in 9.0.

Comment: Unfortunate :(, I have made some progress, not enough though. I have currently been able to Correctly animate my lorenz equations using time, but insofar I haven't been able to alter those parameters.

Comment: For visualization, see also [this answer by @kguler](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2126/245).

Comment: I'm using Mathematic 10 on Linux and I'm unable to get these animations working. I succeed to get the result box ([as show in the screenshot](http://%20https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ugUjBv1lqHTTRBMEFrX2tWS00/view?usp=sharing)), but the animate button is stuck, I can't move it. Any clue ?

Answer (score 6):

You can define a solution function depending on your parameter and then use it for the animation :

```
sol[sigma_] := {x, y, z} /. 
 NDSolve[{x'[t] == sigma (y[t] - x[t]), y'[t] == 28 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
 z'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - 8/3 z[t], x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 2}, 
 {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 25}][[1]]

Animate[
 With[{f = sol[sigma]},
  ParametricPlot3D[{f[[1]][t], f[[2]][t], f[[3]][t]}, {t, 0, 25}]
 ], {sigma, 0, 25}, AnimationRunning -> False
]
```

Comment: For an animation, you probably want to set a fixed `PlotRange` for the `ParametricPlot` (unless you actually want a zoom effect) as well as include option `PerformanceGoal->"Quality"`.

Comment: @murray Thanks, very good suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to do a simple cartoon (as opposed to evaluating the solution components of the Lorenz equations at particular values), you can just directly extract the points generated by `NDSolve[]`. Here's one way to go about it:

```
sol[σ_] := 
 Transpose[Through[{x, y, z}["ValuesOnGrid"] /. 
           First @ NDSolve[{x'[t] == σ (y[t] - x[t]), 
                            y'[t] == 28 x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
                            z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 8 z[t]/3,
                            x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 2}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 25}]]]

Animate[Graphics3D[{Red, Tube[sol[σ]]}, Axes -> True, 
                   PlotRange -> {{-30, 30}, {-30, 30}, {0, 50}}],
        {σ, 0, 25}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image: A Lorenz cartoon]