# Is there a way to add arrows along a parametric curve inside a manipulate function?

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

I cannot find a good way to add arrows along a parametric curve that I used `NDSolve` to get. I have written everything inside `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[ 

Module[{Tf, Tm, Ta, Cp, Caf, km, Ea, Rho, DeltaH, UAV, 
   k, Cps, Qg, Qr, x, sol, p1, p2, p3, p4, z},
  Tf = 298; Tm = 298; Ta = 298; Cp = 4; Caf = 2; km = 0.004; 
  Ea = 1.5*10^4; Rho = 10^3; DeltaH = -2.2*10^5; 
  UAV = 340;

  k[T[t_]] = km*Exp[-Ea*(1/T[t] - 1/Tm)];
  Cps = Rho*Cp;
  Qg[t_] = -k[T[t]]/(1 + k[T[t]]*Tau)*Caf*DeltaH;
  Qr[t_] = Cps/Tau*(T[t] - Tf);
  x[t_] = 1 - Ca[t]/Caf;
  sol = NDSolve[{
     D[Ca[t], {t, 1}] == (Caf - Ca[t])/Tau - k[T[t]]*Ca[t],
     D[T[t], {t, 1}] == 
      UAV/Cps*(Ta - T[t]) + (
       Tf - T[t])/Tau -DeltaH/Cps*k[T[t]]*Ca[t],
     Ca[0] == Cao,
     T[0] == To},
    {Ca[t], T[t]},
    {t, 0, 800}];
  p1 = ParametricPlot[{T[t], x[t]} /. Flatten[sol], {t, 0, 800},
    PlotRange -> {{290, 400}, {0, 1.1}},
    PlotPoints -> Automatic]],
{{Tau,45,""},10,100},
{{To,310,""},298,320},
{{Cao,2.4,""},0,5}]
```

This is the most I can condense it for y'all. I want to add arrows along the solution plotted using `ParametricPlot` I have tried a number of different things but it looks like `Graphics[Arrow[ ]]` is meant more for fixed points and not manipulated curves. Am I right about that or can I put arrows in my plot? I have looked at this post [Plotting a set of trajectories](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/plotting-a-set-of-trajectories-not-a-vector-field-in-3d/) but I've been having a bit of trouble following the code after a certain point.

Yes, I asked this question on Stack Exchange but I was told to come here instead.

Comment: _"but I've been having a bit of trouble following the code after a certain point"_ justifies another type of question ...

Comment: As a hint, ponder upon the result of `ParametricPlot[{t Cos[t], t Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Prepend[ConstantArray[.05, 6], 0]]] /. Line -> Arrow`. The approach should be easily adaptable to your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to read up on a few of those commands.