# 3D Phase Portrait with direction fields and sample solution curves

Tags: differential-equations

I have seen NDSolve and ParamtericPlot3D used for things like the Lorenz Attractor, but was wondering if there is a way to draw a 3D phase portrait for a system.

Something akin to this: http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/35774-Phase-Portrait-In-3D

Does MMA have something built-in to do this and I have just discovered Trekker, but have not explored it and a search did not turn anything up readily.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2099/5

Comment: Can I delete my own question as that answers it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, amzoti. You *can* delete your question, but the StackExchange system allows us to mark this question as a duplicate of the other one. This is fine, as people are directed to the right answer, and some Google searches might find this one more easily than the original. So there is no real harm in having duplicates. It is always a good idea to check on the site first to see if your question has already been answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can use additional packages to plot phase portraits in 3D. For example, using Gianluca Gorni's `CurvesGraphics` package /[link](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/)/ you can do the following:

```
 << "CurvesGraphics6`"

 PhasePlot[{x + 2 y + 3 z, 4 x + 3 y + 2 z, 3 x + y + 2 z}, {x, -1, 1}, 
     {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, {-10, 10}, GridPoints -> 5, 
     PlotStyle -> RGBColor]
```

[image: plot]

Or you can use [DynPac](http://www.me.rochester.edu/courses/ME406/webdown/down.html)