# Is there a 3D version of ListStreamPlot[] (analogous to ListVectorPlot3D[])

Tags: plotting, visualization, vector-calculus

Is there is straightforward way to visualize streamlines given a series of discrete samples of a 3D vector field? There is a generalization of `ListVectorPlot` --> `ListVectorPlot3D`, but I cannot seem to find an equivalent for `ListStreamPlot`

Comment: There is not `StreamPlot3D` right now (so there definitely isn't a `ListStreamPlot3D`), so you'll have to find some way of coding it.  [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/687/9490) asks how to make something like a `StreamPlot3D` and the answers might be usefult to you in this task

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2099/9490) also looks useful.  If you could give the data you want to plot, maybe I could give it a try