# 3d system: stream plot and function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a 3D ODE-system
$$x'=f_1(x,y,z),\quad y'=f_2(x,y,z),\quad z'=f_3(x,y,z)
$$

living on the sphere and an equilibrium $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$. I would like to plot a function $V(x,y,z)$ to see whether t could be a Lyapunov function for this equilibrium. To this end, it would be great to see the stream plot and the function V.

To be more concrete: I have $$x'=x(-x+f(x,y,z)),\quad y'=y(x-y+f(x,y,z)),\quad z'=z(y-z+f(x,y,z))$$

with $f(x,y,z)=x^3-xy^2+y^3-yz^2+z^3$ and the equilibrium $(a,2a,3a)$ with $a=\sqrt{1/14}$.

Here $(x,y,z)\in S^2$ (one-sphere).

Would like to see the stream plot and to plot $V(x,y,z)=(x-a)^2+(y-2a)^2+(z-3a)^2$.

**In particular, I would like to see graphically, if $V$ can be a global Lyapunov-function for $(a,2a,3a)$ on $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: x,y,z>0\}$.** This means that $V>0$ on $M\setminus\{(a,2a,3a)\}$ and $V'<0$ on $M\setminus\{(a,2a,3a)\}$. Maybe one can see on a plot that this is not the case? Then any further analysis would be superfluous...

I tried this for the stream plot (only plotting x and y).

```
z = (1-x^2-y^2)^(1/2)
s= x^3 - x*y^2+y^3-y*z^2+z^3
xdot = x * (-x+s)
ydot = y* (x-y+s)

StreamPlot[{xdot,ydot},{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Mathematica.SE. Then, please show us the code text rather than the screenshot of it, so we can easily test. BTW, sadly there's no `StreamPlot3D` in _Mathematica_ at the moment. Related: 1. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137809/1871 2. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123137/1871 There may be more…

Comment: I added the code and removed the screenshot. - But maybe it is possible to plot everything on the sphere? How can I plot the function $V(x,y,z)$ to see where on the sphere it is positive and decreasing?

Comment: You mean this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65401/1871

Comment: Yes, it would be great to have something like that. I also saw this post bu it was too difficult to me to understand how to use this for my system.

Comment: However, this then does not capture the $z$-dynamics but is only a projection of the x-y-dynamics onto the sphere, isn't it?

Comment: "Here $(x,y,z)\in S^2$ (one-sphere)." Where's the center of the sphere? $(0,0,0)$ or $(a,2a,3a)$? Also, do you want to plot $V(x,y,z)$ or $V(x,y,z)=…$? If the former, `DensityPlot3D`, if the latter, `ContourPlot3D`. "How can I plot the function 
$V(x,y,z)$ to see where on the sphere it is positive and decreasing? " You mean `SliceVectorPlot3D`?

Comment: The center is $(0,0,0)$. I would like to see how $V(x,y,z)$ looks in the neighbourhood of $(a,2a,3a)$. I tried ContourPlot3D[(x-q)^2+(y-2*q)^2+(z-3*q)^2>0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}] but this gives me nothing.

Comment: An example: `q = Sqrt[14]; ContourPlot3D[(x - q)^2 + (y - 2*q)^2 + (z - 3*q)^2 == 
  30, {x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}, {z, -10, 20}]`.

Comment: @Scuderi Check typos. There are no solutions with $a=1/\sqrt{14}$

Comment: In particular, I would like to see (graphically) if $V(x,y,z)=(x-a)^2+(y-2a)^2+(z-3a)^2$ can be a global Lyapunovfunction for $(a,2a,3a)$ on $\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: x,y,z>0\}$.

Comment: @Scuderi There are typos there. Correct please.

Comment: Where do you see typos, there are no typos to my opinion. The function is $f(x,y,z)=x^3-xy^2+y^3-yz^2+z^3$.

Comment: Thank you, now everything is correct. There are 21 points of equilibrium. Why are you researching $(a,2a,3a)$?

Comment: Up to my analysis, there are 14 equilibria and not 21.   --- I am focusing on $(a,2a,3a)$ because it is the only equilibrium in $M:=\{(x,y,z)\in S^2: x,y,z>0\}$ and this part, where all coordinates are positive, plays a special role in my work. - The main motivation for my question here is that I am searching for a Lyapunov-function. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595998/show-global-stability-existence-of-lyapunov-function

Answer (score 10):

OK, after reading Alex's answer and your post in math.SE, I think I somewhat (at least partly) understand the question. First, as to your doubt in the comment:

> However, this then does not capture the $z$ dynamics but is only a projection of the $x$-$y$-dynamics onto the sphere, isn't it?

The answer is no, because the independent variables in [that post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65401/1871) are $\theta$ and $\phi$, the angle components in spherical coordinate. And we can draw the same plot for your vector with proper coordinate transform:

```
f = x^3 - x y^2 + y^3 - y z^2 + z^3;
xdot = x (-x + f);
ydot = y (x - y + f);
zdot = z (y - z + f);
vector = {xdot, ydot, zdot};

a = 1/Sqrt[14];

point = {a, 2 a, 3 a};

transformedvector = 
 TransformedField["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", 
    vector, {x, y, z} -> {r, theta, phi}] /. r -> 1 // Simplify
(*
{0, 
 1/4 Cos[theta] Sin[theta] (4 Cos[theta] + (-2 Cos[phi] - 2 Cos[3 phi] - 7 Sin[phi] + 
       Sin[3 phi]) Sin[theta]), 
 Cos[phi] (2 Cos[phi] - Sin[phi]) Sin[phi] Sin[theta]^2}
*)
```

As one can see, after substituting $r=1$ into the transformed vector, $r$ component of the vector becomes $0$, which indicates all the vectors at $r=1$ are on the unit ball.

Then we plot it in 2D:

```
plot = StreamPlot[
   transformedvector // Rest // Evaluate, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi}]~Show~
  Graphics@{Orange, PointSize@Large, 
    Point@Rest@CoordinateTransform["Cartesian" -> "Spherical", point]}
```

[image]

Well, in my opinion this illustration is already good enough, but if you insist on visualising on the ball:

```
func = {theta, phi} \[Function] 
  Evaluate@CoordinateTransform[
    "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {1, theta, phi}]

plot3D = Graphics3D[(plot[[1]] /. (head : Arrow | Point)[z_] :> 
     head[z /. {x_?NumericQ, y_} :> func @@ {x, y}])]
```

[image]

```
plot3D~Show~Graphics3D@Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 0.98]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Visualization of the solution in the form of trajectories on the sphere

```
eq = {x[t] (-x[t] + x[t]^3 - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
      z[t]^3), 
   y[t] (x[t] + x[t]^3 - y[t] - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
      z[t]^3), 
   z[t] (x[t]^3 + y[t] - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - z[t] - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
      z[t]^3)};

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}, 
   x[0] == Cos[b] Sin[c], y[0] == Sin[b] Sin[c], 
   z[0] == Cos[c]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 20}, {c, b}]

a = 1/Sqrt[14.]; Show[
 Graphics3D[{{Green, Ball[]}, {Orange, PointSize[.05], 
    Point[{a, 2 a, 3 a}]}}, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/12, b], {b, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/3, b], {b, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Let's check if the point `{a,2 a,3 a}` is Lyapunov stable.
We linearize the equation in a neighborhood of this point

```
eq1 = eq /. {x[t] -> a + e x1[t], y[t] -> 2 a + e y1[t], 
   z[t] -> 3 a + e z1[t]};
s1 = Series[eq1, {x1[t], 0, 1}, {y1[t], 0, 1}, {z1[t], 0, 1}] ;
eqL = s1 // Normal;
eql = Series[eqL, {e, 0, 1}] // Normal; eqlp = Chop[eql /. e -> 1]

(*Out[]= {-0.286351 x1[t] - 0.0190901 y1[t] + 0.286351 z1[t], 
 0.496342 x1[t] - 0.572703 y1[t] + 0.572703 z1[t], -0.0572703 x1[t] + 
  0.744513 y1[t] + 0.0572703 z1[t]}*)
```

Matrix of linear system `X'[t] =A.X`

```
A = CoefficientArrays[eqlp, {x1[t], y1[t], z1[t]}] // Normal // Last

(*Out[]= {{-0.286351, -0.0190901, 0.286351}, {0.496342, -0.572703, 
  0.572703}, {-0.0572703, 0.744513, 0.0572703}}*)
```

Finally check

```
LyapunovSolve[
  Transpose[
   A], -{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 
     3}}] // PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ

(*Out[]= False*)
```

Therefore, the system is unstable. Eigenvalues

```
Eigenvalues[A]

(*Out[]= {-0.801784, 0.534522, -0.534522}*)
```

Solution close to the point $(a,2a,3a)$. Code for v.12.1:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}, 
   x[0] == Cos[b] Sin[c], y[0] == Sin[b] Sin[c], 
   z[0] == Cos[c]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {c, b}];
Show[Graphics3D[{Green, Ball[]}, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/12, b], {b, .01, Pi/2, .02}]], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/3, b], {b, 0.01, Pi/2, .02}]], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]
{ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/12, b], {b, .01, Pi/2, .01}]], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/3, b], {b, 0.01, Pi/2, .01}]], {t, 0, 30}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

We see that the trajectories leave the sphere near the point $(a, 2a, 3a)$.Code for v.12.0:

```
eq = {x[t] (-x[t] + x[t]^3 - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
     z[t]^3), 
  y[t] (x[t] + x[t]^3 - y[t] - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
     z[t]^3), 
  z[t] (x[t]^3 + y[t] - x[t] y[t]^2 + y[t]^3 - z[t] - y[t] z[t]^2 + 
     z[t]^3)}; tm = 23; sol = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[{eq == {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}, 
   x[0] == Cos[b] Sin[c], y[0] == Sin[b] Sin[c], 
   z[0] == Cos[c]}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, tm}, {c, b}];
a = 1/Sqrt[14];


Show[Graphics3D[{Green, Opacity[.4], Sphere[]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {1/4, 1}}, Boxed -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/6, b], {b, .01, Pi/2, .02}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/3, b], {b, 0.01, Pi/2, .02}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
  PlotRange -> All]]

Show[{ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/6, b], {b, .01, Pi/2, .01}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[Table[sol[Pi/3, b], {b, 0.01, Pi/2, .01}]], {t, 0, tm}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Wow! The plot suggests that (a,2a,3a) is globally stable on M, doesn‘t it? So there Must be some Lyapunov-function on M. Is there a way to plot functions V(x,y,z) in this plot or another to see if they are possible candidates?

Comment: @Scuderi See update to my answer.

Comment: I agree that in $3d$ the point $(a,2a,3a)$ is a saddle and thus unstable. But isn't this one dimension too much? Because we are only living on the sphere. In some sense the point must be stable as the plot suggests.

Comment: In a numerical solution, we cannot get too close to this point. Therefore, there is an instability that is visible with good resolution - see update.