# How to plot the phase portrait for $4\times 4$ ODE system?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, color, visualization, system

I wrote below the instructions in Mathematica because I wanted to see the phase portrait of systems of DE of $4\times 4$ dimension. But Mathematica cannot recognize the last 2 variables $y$ and $z$ and marks an error.

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
StreamPlot[{b n - d w - w β x - w β1 y,
            β w x - x (d - c - γ),
            β1 w y - (d + c1 + γ1) y,
            γ x + γ1 y - d z},
  {w, -5, 5}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you're trying to do, but it looks like you're trying to make a 4D plot, which is pretty clearly impossible. I think you need to look at the syntax of `StreamPlot` in the documentation.

Comment: @b3m2a1 It's not actually a 4D plot it's a 4D phase portrait.

Comment: So... what do you expect it to look like? What is the expected output, if not a 4D plot? From what I remember of my DEs, phase portraits are in general 2D objects, thus there are 2 independent variables and maybe a parametrized curve laid on top. What do you want the `x`, `y`, and `z` variables to do?

Comment: @b3m2a1, @ OP: For an autonomous system, a "phase portrait" is a plot of some flow lines in phase space.  The dimension of phase space is equal to the number of independent variables, which as you correctly say is four.  2D phase portraits are relatively easy to plot and read.  [*Mathematica* can plot 3D phase portraits](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2099), but they are not particularly easy to read.  There is no built-in support for 4D visualization, so folks have to do their own projections down to 3D and render the result, which is even harder to read.

Comment: The paper, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2005.12.030, tries to visualize a 4D system by projecting onto the 6 coordinate planes corresponding to all 6 pairs of the four variables. This would be possible. Once you select the flow lines, it would be easy.  Don't know if it would be particularly useful though.

Comment: @b3m2a1 A similar behavior as in 2D phase portrait. The variables $x,y,z$ were going to represent a mathematical model. But I'm going to change it, I'm going to take just 2 variables.