# StreamPlot4d: How to visualize some two dimensional StreamPlot type projection for a four dimensional system

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d

This question has essentially been asked before [How to plot the phase portrait for $4\times 4$ ODE system?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164313/how-to-plot-the-phase-portrait-for-4-times-4-ode-system)

Another  good description is at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1379460/plotting-a-4d-dynamical-system

The question is even relevant for-3-times-3-ode-systems, since the output of `StreamPlot3d`  is hard to read

Now we can solve any system with NDSolve, and it will have say two fixed points. One could plot solutions for a grid of initial points, and select a number, say 4 solutions which converge to each of the fixed points. Then, `ParametriPlot' some two dimensional choice of coordinates  for these eight trajectories.  Granted, the 4-dimensional paths might cross in two dimensions, but with luck, the two dimensional projection might be a visually satisfying illustration of the convergence to different fixed points, which is what I need.

Two questions:  1) is the above complete nonsense?

2. There is also a package https://github.com/mekeetsa/StreamPlot4d which I haven't been able to install yet.  I tried to save it in the AddOns, but Mathematica 13.3 refused to unpack  the zip file there

I dragged, unpacked it and executed it the m.file in the current directory, but then

<< StreamPlot4D`

resulted in

```
Get::path: Directory in $Path is not a string.
```

There are no instructions in the package on how to install it, it must be too simple :(

Answer (score 3):

- After download and unzipping the package in the Mathematica's Autoload folder, I got a $Failed message as I tried to load the package.
- Then I renamed the folder to remove `master` (circled in red on the image below) and tried again. It works as you can see. I am running v12.2 on Win7-x64.

[image]

**EDIT**

`C:\ProgramData\Mathematica\Autoload` happens to be the Autoload folder on my machine. It may be elsewhere on other setups.