# Mathematica slope fields

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a slope field. Here is the code

```
slopefield = 
 VectorPlot[{1, .005 * p*(10 - p) }, {t, -1.5, 20}, {p, -10, 16}, 
  Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {t, p},  Axes -> True, 
  VectorScale -> {Tiny, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 15]
```

I solved the differential equations and plotted the curves manually. Three questions:

1. Is there an easier way to do it?
2. Ticks -> None doesn't seems to work. I still get labels for the tick marks.
3. I'd like to selectively label 2 tick marks.

Comment: What do you mean by _manually_??

Comment: Related questions that address the issue of drawing stream line curves are "[Sketching solution curves for differential equations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6798539/915703)" and "[I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/687/245)"

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming here that the curves you mentioned are streamlines of the vector field. You can plot those automatically without having to solve any differential equations by using the options `StreamPoints`, for example to plot the stream lines going through the points

```
points =  Transpose@ArrayPad[{Range[-10, 16, 2]}, {{1, 0}, {0, 0}}]

(* ==> {{0, -10}, {0, -8}, {0, -6}, {0, -4}, {0, -2}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}, {0, 4}, 
        {0, 6}, {0, 8}, {0, 10}, {0, 12}, {0, 14}, {0, 16}} *)
```

you can do

```
slopefield = 
 VectorPlot[{1, .005*p*(10 - p)}, {t, -1.5, 20}, {p, -10, 16}, 
  FrameTicks -> None, AxesLabel -> {t, p}, Axes -> True, 
  VectorScale -> {Tiny, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 15, 
  StreamPoints -> points,
  StreamStyle -> {Red, "Line"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oi my! I did not understand what he meant by _plotted the curves manually._ ! :)

Comment: @belisarius I'm just guessing here. I don't know for sure if that's what the OP meant.

Answer (score 3):

To plot the vector field and the streamlines (curves) together, there are two other plot functions that are specialized for this purpose:

- [`StreamPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StreamPlot.html)
- [`LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html)

The difference to `VectorPlot` is that Mathematica can automatically pick a set of curves for you. You can specify the starting points for the curves, but you don't have to:

```
StreamPlot[{1, .005*p*(10 - p)}, {t, -1.5, 20}, {p, -10, 16}, 
 AxesLabel -> {t, p}, Axes -> True, 
 VectorScale -> {Tiny, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 15,
 StreamStyle -> Red, FrameTicks -> {{5, 10}, {-10, 10}, {}, {}}]
```

[image: StremPlot]

Here, I've also added a `FrameTicks` specification that labels several special points on the horizontal and vertical axes.

The other alternative, which contains some additional visual information, is this:

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{1, .005*p*(10 - p)}, {t, -1.5, 
  20}, {p, -10, 16}, Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {t, p}, Axes -> True,
  VectorScale -> {Tiny, Automatic, None}, VectorPoints -> 15, 
 VectorStyle -> LightGray, ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"], 
 FrameTicks -> {{5, 10}, {-10, 10}, {}, {}}, Background -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> White, FrameTicksStyle -> Yellow, ImageMargins -> 5]
```

[image: convolution plot]

The last plot can be customized by adding the actual streamlines with the `StreamPoints` option (see the documentation), but the colored background serves the same purpose. The idea is that the background pattern is physically like the pattern you'd get (e.g.) from grass seeds in an electric field, or irons filings in a magnetic field, etc. And of course the color encodes information about the field strength.

Comment: Actually, You don't need to explicitly specify the starting points for the streamlines in  `VectorPlot`. You can also do something like `StreamPoints -> 16` which will plot 16 strategically placed streamlines.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
VectorPlot[{1, .005*p*(10 - p)}, {t, -1.5, 20}, {p, -10, 16}, 
          FrameTicks -> {
              Join[{{0, "ZERO", {0, .1}, Red}}, Table[{i, ""}, {i, -1.5, 20, 3}]], 
                                                Table[{i, ""}, {i, -10, 16, 3}]}, 
          AxesLabel -> {t, p}, 
          Frame     -> True, 
          VectorScale -> {Tiny, Automatic, None}, 
          VectorPoints -> 15]
```

[image]