# How to get StreamPlot to draw many hundreds of streamlines?

Tags: plotting, generative-art

For artistic reasons, I want to draw an extremely dense `StreamPlot` with something like a thousand streamlines. I tried setting `StreamPoints -> {Automatic, d}` where $d$ is a small value specifying the minimum distance between streamlines, but after a point reducing the value of $d$ stops having an effect.

```
GraphicsColumn[
 StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
    StreamPoints -> {Automatic, #}, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ {1, 0.3,
    0.1, 0.03, 0.01}]
```

[image]

The same thing happens when setting `StreamPoints -> n` for increasing values of $n$, or when manually seeding hundreds of seed points; Mathematica silently refuses to plot any more streamlines.

How can I get around this? Is it possible to plot arbitrarily closely spaced streamlines using `StreamPlot`?

**Update:** To clarify, I want to keep the style of the fully-automatic default `StreamPlot`, which attempts to maintain a uniform spacing between streamlines, and just make it denser. So I don't want to get rid of the minimum distance entirely; I just want to lower it. To save everyone some time, here is what I find unsatisfactory about all the documented settings for `StreamPoints`.

- `None`: Obviously no good.
- $n$: Stops having an effect somewhere between 50 and 100.
- `Automatic`, `Coarse`, and `Fine`: Not dense enough.
- `{p1, p2, ...}` and `{{p1, g1}, ...}`: See `n`.
- `{spec, d}`: `d` stops having an effect somewhere between 0.2 and 0.1.
- `{spec, {dStart, dEnd}}`: Strangely, increasing `dEnd` plots *more* streamlines. Compare `{Automatic, {0.5, 10}}` with `{Automatic, 0.5}` and `{Automatic, {0.5, 0.5}}`. I don't understand this setting at all.
- `{spec, d, len}`: When `spec` is `Automatic`, `len` has no effect as far as I can tell. On the other hand, when `spec` is `{p1, p2, ...}`, `len` causes `d` to be ignored completely.

Comment: Are you sure?  Your 3rd & 4th images above are different.  Please check again but using ImageSize->(eg) 700 so you can see differences.

Comment: @dwa: They are slightly different, but the fourth image is certainly not 3 times denser. I've updated with a hopefully more convincing example.

Comment: Great question.  Now I have reason to explore the inner workings of StreamPlot, which I've never really considered before.

Comment: Actually, the uniform spacing between streamlines that you like so much isn't really that useful. In many applications, one wants the streamline density to vary with the field strength. The automatic minimum distance actually prevents that! So I find it necessary to choose my own seed points to make sure that the function is represented faithfully. When you ask for longer streamlines, it becomes harder on average to enforce a minimum separation, and spacings that look even in one region may not in another region.

Comment: Two related questions: [Mathematica slope fields](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4612/245) and [I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/687/245)

Comment: @Jens: 1. It doesn't have to be useful. This is for artistic reasons as I said in the question, not for any sort of serious data visualization. 2. Of course, choosing seed points is enough to make density proportional to the field strength only when the vector field is divergence-free. And even so, getting the right density can be pretty hard; compare `{-y, x}` and `-y/(x^2+y^2), x/(x^2+y^2)`, and I have no idea what to do for an arbitrary divergence-free vector field. 3. Yes, I don't need arbitrarily long streamlines. I was just describing the effects of all the settings for completeness.

Comment: Of course, your points are valid independent of whether it's useful or not. Note that I'm not saying streamline density has to be _proportional_ to field strength, but having it vary non-uniformly can in fact carry useful information.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: How *does* one explore the inner workings of StreamPlot?

Answer (score 42):

Maybe this isn't what you need, but for aesthetic reasons I would suggest for such a high streamline density to use a *different* plot altogether:

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 2, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, RasterSize -> 300]
```

[image: convolutionPlot1]

```
LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, 
  Image[Table[((-1)^i (-1)^j + 1)/2, {i, 45}, {j, 45}]]}, {x, -3, 
  3}, {y, -3, 3}, LineIntegralConvolutionScale -> 2, 
 ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, RasterSize -> 300]
```

[image: convolutionPlot2]

There are many additional options for [`LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html), but I like its smoothed, continuous representation of the streamlines.

**Edit**

Here is a simple way to create arbitrary many streamlines by circumventing the ceiling that `StreamPlot` appears to impose on us:

```
t = Map[StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
      3}, StreamStyle -> "Line", 
     StreamPoints -> RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {#, 2}], ImageSize -> 500] &,
    ConstantArray[50, 20]];

Show[t]
```

[image: streamplot]

The trick I used is to generate a whole list of `StreamPlot`s, all with different seed points (here chosen randomly, but you could tweak that at will). Each single plot is given a fixed number of seed points that doesn't have to be very large (here `50`).

But then I superimpose all these plots using `Show`, and the result is an arbitrarily dense array of stream lines because the individual plots don't know anything about how close stream lines in the other plots are.

**Edit 2**

For fun, I made this stream plot with nominally `5000` seed points, and gave it random gray scales to see how similar it looks to the `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot` above. Here is the result:

```
t = Map[StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
      3}, StreamStyle -> "Line", 
     StreamPoints -> RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {#, 2}], 
     StreamColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[RandomReal[]] &), 
     ImageSize -> 500] &, ConstantArray[50, 100]];

Show[t]
```

[image: gray stream lines]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of line integral convolution, but I really do want a streamline plot. I'll be rendering it with `StreamStyle -> "Line"` and `ImageSize -> Large` if that helps convince you of the aesthetic I'm going for.

Comment: @RahulNarain OK, this really is a different problem then. I'll edit my answer to address this shortcoming.

Comment: Clever! +1. However, what makes the output of `StreamPlot` nice is that it attempts to keep the streamlines uniformly spaced, which is no longer the case with this approach.

Comment: The spacing depends only on your choice of seed points.

Comment: @Jens: Very cool and informative approach.

Comment: I've updated the question; sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks a lot: I used your approach in my thesis, and it looked pretty good!

Answer (score 28):

It seems to help to include a maximum length in the `StreamPoints` setting:

```
StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 StreamPoints -> {Tuples[Range[-3, 3, 0.2], 2], Automatic, 10}, 
 ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"]
```

[image]

```
Count[%, _Line, -1]
(* 960 *)
```

Comment: Interesting observation (+1).

Comment: Interesting. However, it seems this only works by overriding the minimum distance between streamlines. Now the streamlines are nonuniformly dense (e.g. lower right), even after replacing `Automatic` with a fixed value. Also, this doesn't work when using automatic seed points instead of `Tuples[...]`.

Comment: I've updated the question; sorry about the confusion.

Comment: This inhomogeneity seems to me quite unavoidable as a result of the fact that you can't predict that the spacing will remain uniform everywhere if you set it to be approximately uniform in some subregion of the plot. Maybe the reason this answer works in the first place is that _Mathematica_ knows about this uncertainty and stops obsessing about minimum separation when you ask for long stream lines where it becomes too hard to predict the separation over long "times" on the streamline.

Comment: @Jens, *Mathematica* normally deals with the non-uniform density by terminating some of the streamlines as their spacing decreases. It's not clear to me why this stops happening when you specify a **maximum** length for the streamlines.

Answer (score 8):

**Edit:** I've found the error I've had, fixed it, and generalized the solution:

The new function `denseStreamPlot` is now 4 different functions that you could use:

```
Subdivide2D[{xmin_, xmax_, nx_}, {ymin_, ymax_, ny_}] := 
 Tuples[{Subdivide[xmin, xmax, nx], Subdivide[ymin, ymax, ny]}]
Subdivide2D[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, n_] := 
 Subdivide2D[{xmin, xmax, n }, {ymin, ymax, n}]
AddPoints[p1_, p2_] := {p1[[1]] + p2[[1]], p1[[2]] + p2[[2]]}


getStreamPointsBiDiagonal[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}] := 
 Module[{innerCellPoints, lastSets, sets}, 
  sets = Partition[
    Subdivide2D[{xmin, xmax, n - 1}, {ymin, ymax, n - 1}], n];
  lastSets = {sets[[-1]], (Transpose@sets)[[-1]]};
  sets = sets[[;; -2, ;; -2]];
  innerCellPoints = 
   Table[{i (ymax - ymin)/(
      k (n - 1)), (1 - (-1)^i)/2 (ymax - ymin)/(n - 1) + 
      i (-1)^i (ymax - ymin)/(k (n - 1))} , {i, 0, k - 1}];
  sets = Join[
    Flatten[Table[
      Table[AddPoints[pt, #] & /@ set, {set, sets}], {pt, 
       innerCellPoints}], 1], lastSets]]

SetAttributes[denseStreamPlot, {HoldAll}];
denseStreamPlot[expr_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
  streamPointsMethod_Symbol: getStreamPointsBiDiagonal, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{innerCellPoints, lastSets, sets},
  Show[StreamPlot[expr, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
      StreamPoints -> #, opts] & /@ 
    streamPointsMethod[{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}]]]
```

In here, the function `denseStreamPlot` plots the actual graph, and the function `getStreamPointsBiDiagonal` gives the point-sets for the streams. For example, the code

```
n = 6;
k = 10;
GraphicsRow[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium],
  Show[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"],
    ListPlot[Flatten[getStreamPointsBiDiagonal[{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}], 1], 
     PlotStyle -> Red]}],
  denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"]}
 ]
```

produces
[image]
where the red dots are the plot-points. `n` is the division of the region to a grid of `n` by `n`, and every cell in this grid is divided into `k` points inside the cell, and it's seen in this plot.

I've kept the option to change the StreamPointFunction as you will, so, for instance, define

```
getStreamPointsDiagonal[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}] := 
 Module[{innerCellPoints, lastSets, sets}, 
  sets = Partition[
    Subdivide2D[{xmin, xmax, n - 1}, {ymin, ymax, n - 1}], n];
  lastSets = {sets[[-1]], (Transpose@sets)[[-1]]};
  sets = sets[[;; -2, ;; -2]];
  innerCellPoints = 
   Table[{i (ymax - ymin)/(k (n - 1)), 
     i (ymax - ymin)/(k (n - 1))} , {i, 0, k - 1}];
  sets = Join[
    Flatten[Table[
      Table[AddPoints[pt, #] & /@ set, {set, sets}], {pt, 
       innerCellPoints}], 1], lastSets]]
```

and run the same line of code above, only with the `getStreamPointsDiagonal` function to get

```
n = 6;
k = 10;

GraphicsRow[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -3, 3}, getStreamPointsDiagonal, ImageSize -> Medium],
  Show[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"],
    ListPlot[Flatten[getStreamPointsDiagonal[{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}], 1], 
     PlotStyle -> Red]}],
  denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    getStreamPointsDiagonal, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   StreamStyle -> "Line"]}
 ]
```

[image]

The old errorous function can be reobtained as a special case of the above code:

```
n = 2;
k = 150;
GraphicsRow[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -3, 3}, getStreamPointsDiagonal, ImageSize -> Medium],
  Show[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
      3}, {y, -3, 3}, getStreamPointsDiagonal, ImageSize -> Medium, 
     StreamStyle -> "Line"],
    ListPlot[Flatten[getStreamPointsDiagonal[{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}], 1], 
     PlotStyle -> Red]}],
  denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    getStreamPointsDiagonal, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   StreamStyle -> "Line"]}
 ]
```

[image]
**Original Answer:**
I've used @Jens's approach to create a uniformly-spaced answer.
Just copy the following functions:

```
n = 10;
k = 15;
SetAttributes[denseRandomStreamPlot, {HoldAll}];
denseRandomStreamPlot[expr_, rng1_, rng2_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  Show@Map[
   StreamPlot[expr, rng1, rng2, 
     StreamPoints -> 
      Transpose[{RandomReal[rng1[[2 ;;]], #], 
        RandomReal[rng2[[2 ;;]], #]}], opts] &, ConstantArray[n, k]]
```

and

```
SetAttributes[denseStreamPlot, {HoldAll}];
denseStreamPlot[expr_, {x_, xmin_, xmax_}, {y_, ymin_, ymax_}, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{nn, samp, sets},
  sets =
   Table[Transpose[{Subdivide[xmin, xmax - (xmax - (xmin))/n, n - 1], 
       Subdivide[ymin, ymax - (ymax - (ymin))/n, n - 1]}] + 
     Transpose[{ConstantArray[i (xmax - xmin)/(n k), n], 
       ConstantArray[i (ymax - ymin)/(n k), n]}], {i, 0, k}];
  Show@(StreamPlot[expr, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
       StreamPoints -> #, opts] & /@ sets)]
```

In here there are two functions - `denseRandomStreamPlot` & `denseStreamPlot`. `denseRandomStreamPlot` is just an encapsulation of @Jens's anwer. Meaning that the code

```
n = 50;
k = 20;
GraphicsRow[{denseRandomStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 
    1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium],
  denseRandomStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"]}]
```

outputs (I think it's better with arrows)
[image: Random plots]

The other function is my attempt to do the same thing while using different evenly-spaced substitutions of the 2D region. Meaning that the code,

```
n = 10;
k = 20;
GraphicsRow[{denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
  denseStreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    ImageSize -> Medium, StreamStyle -> "Line"]}]
```

gives

[image]

Note that the evenly-spaced points method doesn't work properly in this case (I don't know why), but it works quite well for other fields I've tried. For example, in the case of a simple pendulum,

```
n = 10;
k = 10;
denseStreamPlot[{p, -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, \
{p, -4, 4}, StreamColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

produces

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's a stupidly simple thing I came up with for my own question: just divide the domain into smaller blocks, make separate `StreamPlot`s for each of them, and stitch them together.

```
f[x_, y_] := {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2};
xrange = {-3, 3};
yrange = {-3, 3};
xdivs = 3;
ydivs = 3;
xranges = Partition[Rescale[Range[0, xdivs], {0, xdivs}, xrange], 2, 1];
yranges = Partition[Rescale[Range[0, ydivs], {0, ydivs}, yrange], 2, 1];
(* Yuck. What's a more elegant way to get the subranges? *)

Show[Flatten@
  Table[StreamPlot[
    f[x, y], {x, First@xr, Last@xr}, {y, First@yr, Last@yr}, 
    StreamScale -> {0.2, Automatic, 0.01}, StreamPoints -> 100], {xr, 
    xranges}, {yr, yranges}], PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

It's not perfect because you can clearly see the block boundaries, but it retains `StreamPlot`'s nearly uniform streamline spacing.