# How can I get better control over StreamPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, output-formatting

I'm having some difficulties with the command `StreamPlot` in *Mathematica 7.0*.
Here's the basic plots I'm doing :

```
StreamPlot[{x, -y}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Axes -> True,
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameTicks -> None, 
StreamPoints -> 12, StreamScale -> 0.15, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]

StreamPlot[{y, x}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Axes -> True, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, FrameTicks -> None, StreamPoints -> 12, 
StreamScale -> 0.15, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

Here's the output, which I find ugly :

[image: Ugly output]

- How can I define the number of arrows heads to be drawn on each curve?
  Currently, there are too many arrows on the curves. I would prefer a maximum of two (or maybe three) arrows per stream curve.
- How can I make the output perfectly symetric? Look for example at the second picture, which is terrible.
- How can I remove the straight stream lines?

Comment: Which straight lines are you referring to, the axes (black) or the streams (blue)?

Comment: The straight lines (curves) are the straight streams (blue), of course.  They are useless.  I could remove them by double-clicking on the output graphics, but I would prefer a better method, from the input instead.

Comment: I think you'll have to define `StreamPoints` explicitly to get rid of the straight lines. This could also be the solution to your symmetry problem. FWIW, this is perfectly symmetric by default on Mathematica 9.

Comment: Another problem you may encounter is that *Mathematica* tries to avoid streamlines getting too close to each other, which will mean it may not draw lines for all your `StreamPoints` if they are too close to each other. This is addressed in the question [How to get StreamPlot to draw many hundreds of streamlines?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15895/245)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To make it more symmetric, you can manually specify `StreamPoints`.

To get rid of straight line, you can delete corresponding start points in `StreamPoints`.

To reduce the segmentation, you can manually specify `StreamScale`.

```
points = DeleteCases[
   Tuples[Range[-2, 2, 1/2], 2],
   pt_ /;
    Not[FreeQ[pt, -2 | 0 | 2]] ||
     Abs[pt[[1]]] == Abs[pt[[2]]]
   ];

StreamPlot[{y, x}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
           StreamPoints -> {points, Automatic},
           StreamScale -> {
                           {0.4, 0.01}, (* or use Full to completely prevent segmentation *)
                           All, 0.02, Automatic}
          ]
```

[image: streamplots]

A possible finer tuning would be to generating `points` according to the specific field we want to plot.

---

**Edit: Another set of start points**

For the first plot:

```
points = With[{d = .1},
   Join[#, -#] &[
    {#, -2 + d} & /@
     DeleteCases[Range[-2, 2, 1/5],
      x_ /; Not[FreeQ[x, -2 | 0 | 2]]]
    ]];
```

For the second plot:

```
points = With[{d = .1},
   Join[#, Reverse /@ #] &@
      Join[#, -#] &@
    ({-2 + d, #} & /@ DeleteCases[Range[0, 2, 1/4], 2])
   ];
```

[image: streamplots 2]

Comment: Your second plot is still asymmetric.

Comment: @CoreyKelly Hope we can call it symmetric now! :D

Comment: Also try this point list:  `points = DeleteCases[Tuples[Range[-2, 2, 1/2], 2], 
  pt_ /; Not[FreeQ[pt, -2 | 2]] || 
      Not[FreeQ[pt, 0]] && Total[Abs[pt]] != 1/2 || 
    Abs[pt[[1]]] == Abs[pt[[2]]]]`

Comment: @shrx Better on the 2nd plot! But it introduces straight lines into 1st plot. So to do it better, adaptive start points sampling are necessary.