# How to draw an electric field without additional flux created in the middle of spreading from the charge?

Tags: plotting

I would like to draw an electric field.
But from the condition of the electric field itself, the lines(or flux) should not be created again in the process of getting farther from the origin(or charge).

But as you can see from the output of `StreamPlot` below, it creates several, more stream lines in the middle of stream lines directly from the origin getting spread.

```
k = 1; x0 = 0; y0 = 0;
StreamPlot[{k (x - x0)/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)^(3/2), 
  k (y - y0)/((x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2)^(3/2)}, {x, -50, 50}, {y, -50, 
  50}]
```

[image]

Comment: Try reducing the number of stream lines plotted using the `StreamPoints` option; e.g. `StreamPoints -> 32`. This is what I get: [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dABOU.png).

Comment: Previously: [How do I plot a proper streamline plot, including spacings and line endings?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41748/484)

Comment: This problem has been studied by Tyrone Curtis in his Mathematica 5 notebook : http://users.df.uba.ar/vera/fisica3_12010_files/material_adicional/2D-cargas-puntuales.nb . It must be adapted to your version of Mathematica. It shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41748/how-do-i-plot-a-proper-streamline-plot-including-spacings-and-line-endings check this！

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricFieldLinesDueToACollectionOfPointCharges/, which is an excellent demonstration for teaching electrostatics.