# How to make a StreamPlot with three variables and two expressions

Tags: plotting, syntax

I'm trying to make a StreamPlot in Mathematica with three variables. I already have two variables, x and y, that make an ellipse via

```
StreamPlot[{-y,x}]
```

but I want the vectors to increase as you move radially out from the center (ie ideally I would want a third variable, v, so that it looked like

```
StreamPlot[{-v*y, v*x}]
```

So that as  v increased the vectors increased as well.

Comment: You might take a look at `VectorPlot`.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but it sounds like you're looking for the formula of a vector field in just two variables with such a property.  Something like `Norm[{x, y}]*{-y, x}`.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you're looking for; rescaling the vectors as you propose won't change the stream lines at all.  Are you looking for the actual arrowheads & lines in `StreamPlot` to be rescaled according to their location on in the plot?

Comment: Yes, @MichaelSeifert, that's what I'm looking for. The farther you go out from the center, I want the actual lines to be larger. What I'm doing is making an ellipse, and as you move outward the velocity around the ellipse should increase.

Comment: The vector field {x,-y} produces sets of lines that converge to x=0, not an ellipse

Comment: @Katie Right, sorry: I had an error. I would still suggest using `VectorPlot`. I'm pretty sure it's exactly what you want.

Comment: The problem with VectorPlot is that the number of variables has to match the number of expressions- I can't simply add in another variable to my ellipse

Comment: @Katie: `VectorPlot` scales the vectors automatically, in (I think) exactly the way you want, and there is an option `VectorScale` that allows you to change how the vectors scale. There is also an option in `StreamPlot` called `StreamScale` which will do what you want (I think). Check out the documentation for more information on these.

Comment: Did the answer below answer your question? It is customary to accept a solution by [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t) if it has actually solved your problem. If I haven't, please let me know how I can offer further help.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option in `StreamPlot` called `StreamScale` that allows you to scale the vectors. In the documentation, we find that `StreamScale -> {Automatic, 2, Automatic}` results in scaled vectors. Alternatively, you can use `VectorPlot`, which automatically scales the vectors. Using

```
StreamPlot[{-y,x}, {x,-2,2}, {y,-2,2}, StreamScale -> {Automatic, 2, Automatic}]
VectorPlot[{-y,x}, {x,-2,2}, {y,-2,2}]
```

the results look like (with `StreamPlot` on the left and `VectorPlot` on the right):

[image]

Also see, for instance, [Getting clearer StreamPlot output](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32985/getting-clearer-streamplot-output), [How to get StreamPlot to draw many hundreds of streamlines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/how-to-get-streamplot-to-draw-many-hundreds-of-streamlines?lq=1), and [How can I get better control over StreamPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27319/how-can-i-get-better-control-over-streamplot) for more information about how `StreamPlot` works.