# Why does StreamColorFunctionScaling refuse to turn off?

Tags: plotting, bugs, color

Consider this simple streamline plot:

```
StreamPlot[{-y/10, x/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[v]]]
```

[image]

The arguments to the colour function are rescaled to lie between 0 and 1, so the colours span the whole spectrum, as expected.

But now I want to turn off colour function scaling and work with the original vector field values. Those lie between -1/10 and 1/10, so I should get only hues between purple and orange:

```
StreamPlot[{-y/10, x/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, Hue[v]], 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

*I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.*

Is this a bug? How do I work around it?

Comment: If I `Print` out the values of `x`, `y`, `u` and `v` that are being passed to the color function, `v` is not `x/10`, which is surprising.

Comment: The scaling is "affected" by turning off `StreamColorFunctionScaling`, but not in the correct *way*. It's definitely not a behavior that a sane person would expect. But *Mathematica* is probably thinking it's doing what's best for the mission...

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've reported it, and we'll take a look.

Comment: "*I'm sorry, Dave.*" LOL

Comment: @rcollyer: You should take a look at ChadK's answer. As far as I can tell, the bug is that Mathematica's behaviour is inconsistent with its documentation.

Comment: @RahulNarain I am. I have my suspicions that I know the guy, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `StreamColorFunction` has different arguments than you expect.  It is actually like this:
`{x, y, u/um, v/um, um}`, where $um = Sqrt[u^2+v^2]$.

So all you need to do is redefine your function to account for this:

```
StreamPlot[{-y/10, x/10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 StreamColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v, um}, Hue[u*um]], 
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your contribution.  Please consider selecting a more "human" name, by the way.

Comment: But what if I rescale everything by choosing the plot function and range as `{-y/100,x/100},{x,0,10},{y,0,10}`? It's wrong again. I don't think the order you're assuming works correctly.

Comment: It looks like this works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works after correcting the order of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  Sorry about the mistakes in the first draft (and sloppiness in the second).

Comment: What are the chances that someone signed up just to answer my question? I feel honoured. :)

Answer (score 7):

A work-around:

```
vv = {};
StreamPlot[{-y/10., x/10.}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  StreamColorFunction -> (AppendTo[vv, #4] &)];

With[{MinMax = Through[{Min, Max}[vv]]},
 StreamPlot[{-y/10., x/10.}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> (Hue[Rescale[#4, MinMax, {-.1, .1}]] &)]
]
```

[image]

Comment: You should probably find the `Min` and `Max` values of `vv` outside of the `Function`, and inject them; as written this runs that part repeatedly.  It may or may not matter but it seems like bad style.

Comment: I am going to take the liberty of making the change described above.  If you don't like it you can revert it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Just noticed you comment. Thank you for the edit.