# Wind Map Artwork

Tags: visualization, generative-art

I would like some help generating an image like the one seen below.

[image]

The image above is an [art piece](http://memory.org/point.b/windmap.html) called *Wind Map* by artists Fernanda Viégas and Martin Wattenberg.

I would like to take wind data using `WeatherData` and generate a map like the one above. Eventually I would like to generalize this idea to taking data from the [National Digital Forecast Database](http://ndfd.weather.gov/technical.htm).

I see that it is possible to [generate a coarse wind map](http://wolfram.com/xid/0b8emwqsma-fw6nrf). When I execute that code I get the following output which is similar to what I desire, but there is still much to be done.

[image]

Comment: A couple weeks ago I was playing with a Julia script that launches a bunch of particles on a grid leaving trails behind them, and they follow a vector field defined on the grid, generating somewhat similar visual patterns as in the artwork, but it's not exactly the same method. Figuring out how the artists get their vector field and do their plotting will probably be half the work, and the rest will be figuring out how to make Mathematica give a nice-looking picture. Good luck to everyone who takes the time to answer the question!

Comment: Oops, never mind, they describe where they get the data and technique from in their "Read More" section.

Comment: You could also try `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot`.

Comment: Related Q/A: [(15895)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15895/17).

Answer (score 18):

## Update

According to [KennyColnago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3246/kennycolnago)'s advice, post-processing is not needed, as `StreamColorFunction` can handle it essentially by using `VertexColors` on `Line`-s:

```
ListStreamPlot[
               testdata,
               StreamPoints -> {samplePoints, Automatic, 10},
               StreamStyle -> "Line",
               Background -> Black,
               StreamColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1, #5] &)
              ]
```

## Original

With [Simon Woods' neat trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15911/17) and some post-processing:

```
testdata = Table[{{x, y}, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 2]}, {x, -3, 3, 1}, {y, -3, 3, 1}] // Flatten[#,1]&;

samplePoints = Tuples[Range[-3, 3, 1/5], 2];

ListStreamPlot[
               testdata,
               StreamPoints -> {samplePoints, Automatic, 10},
               StreamStyle -> "Line",
               Background -> Black
              ] //
      # /. ln : Line[idxes_] :>
                    MapIndexed[
                               {
                                GrayLevel[1, 1 - Rescale[#2[[1]], {1, Length[idxes] - 1}]],
                                Line[#1]
                               } &,
                               Partition[idxes, 2, 1]
                              ] &
```

[image: random wind map]

Note for a more meaningful graphics, one might want to determine the `GrayLevel` according to the local wind scale.

Comment: Colouring according to the wind scale may be accomplished with, for example, `StreamColorFunction->(ColorData["DarkRainbow",#5]&)`. Slot #5 corresponds to `Norm[{vx,vy}]`.

Comment: @KennyColnago Great! Much more efficient! (Didn't realize that `Line` can have `VertexColors` too..)

Comment: @Silvia, +1, but where' the map?

Comment: @alancalvitti My apologize. Don't know why, but fetching the online data always time-out here, so I only showed the basic idea.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are lots of things one might try -- here is an attempt using some of the built in options that are available in ListStreamPlot:

```
Show[Graphics[{Black, CountryData["USA", "Polygon"]}], 
 ListStreamPlot[
  Table[{{x, y}, 
    Through[{Cos, Sin}[
      WeatherData[{y, x}, "WindDirection"]]]}, {x, -140, -70, 5}, {y, 
    24, 50, 5}], StreamScale -> Full, StreamStyle -> "Toothpick", 
  StreamColorFunction -> GrayLevel, 
  StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know how it's done, but the original picture gives a sense of "wind direction" that is (at least for me) absent in your picture

Comment: I see wind directions in bills picture, and it also has its own qualities.