# How to force rendering of streamlines in StreamPlot?

Tags: graphics

`StreamPlot` decides on its own what streamlines to show, even when I explicitly specify `StreamPoints`. For example: If I say

```
StreamPlot[{1, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamPoints -> {{-3, 0}, {-3, 0.2}}]
```

`StreamPlot` shows two streamlines. However, if I try

```
StreamPlot[{1, 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamPoints -> {{-3, 0}, {-3, 0.1}}]
```

then it refuses to show me the second streamline, presumably because it's "too close". I would like to force it show me that streamline no matter what.  I tried playing around with some other options (some of which are documented quite poorly...), but no matter what I try I can't get `StreamPlot` to not eliminate streamlines altogether that are too close to others, or stop drawing streamlines once they get too close to others. For example, changing the size of the arrows has no effect on `StreamPlot`'s decision as to what minimum distance of streamlines to accept.

Comment: You might find something helpful here [15895](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/how-to-get-streamplot-to-draw-many-hundreds-of-streamlines)

Comment: Excellent! This does what I want. The secret was the maximum length in the `StreamPoints` setting. Of course, the post you linked to has other helpful tricks, too...