# Force exact number of streamlines in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The [StreamPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) command has an option for the number of `StreamPoints`.

When I try the first it does not appear to allow you to choose anything other than $10$ (for example, I want to plot $1000$ streamlines)

```
StreamPlot[{10 x y - 1/2 x - 1/10 x^2, y - y^2 - x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 
 0, 1/2}, StreamPoints -> 10]
```

When I try a second variant, it is a slight improvement as

```
StreamPlot[{10 x y - 1/2 x - 1/10 x^2, y - y^2 - x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 
 0, 1/2}, ImageSize -> Large, StreamPoints -> Fine]
```

However, how can I get MMA to add as many, say $1000$ streamlines, in the first quadrant using `StreamPlot`?

Perhaps there are other approaches using `NDSolve` and the like, but why can this not be done with `StreamPlot`?

Comment: Maybe some clever manipulation of `VectorPoints`? Or something along the lines of the `Contours` option for `ContourPlot`?

Comment: Interesting, I will think about those options.

Comment: Here's a really dirty start `Show[StreamPlot[{10. x y - .5 x - .1 x^2, y - y^2 - x y},{x, 0., 3.}, {y, 0., #}, StreamPoints -> 1, StreamStyle -> Arrowheads[.015]] & /@ Subdivide[0.01, .5, 100], PlotRange -> All]`.  Granted this is only for (still at most) 100 lines.  I tried 1000, but it just didn't look very good.  Also note, that the resulting plot only has `0 < y < .3`.

Comment: Have you considered `LineIntegralConvolutionPlot[{10 x y - 1/2 x - 1/10 x^2, 
  y - y^2 - x y}, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 1/2}, RasterSize -> 300]`?

Comment: @JimB: Neat! I will have to look at this more, but that is much better! I want to see if it lets me do more color separation to better see the lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/how-to-get-streamplot-to-draw-many-hundreds-of-streamlines.