# how to create a slope field in mathematica?

Tags: plotting

Anyone have any good resources for learning mathematics, already sufficient in JAVA. not math... only in calc 2.

I want to plot the slope field of `y(x)= (1200e^(kx))/ (c + e^(kx))`?

Any suggestions?

Code so far.

```
VectorPlot[{1, 1200 e^kx/c + e^kx} {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: If `e` is meant to be the constant `e` it should be `E` in Mathematica. Also in order to multiply variables you have to have a space in between them, so `k x` and not `kx`, possibly with parenthesis to tell *Mathematica* that `E` is raised to `k x` and not just `k`. Besides syntax problems, this looks like a sound start. Please take a look at previous related question such [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/how-to-visualize-slope-fields-of-differential-equations-without-vectors).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mathematica slope fields](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/mathematica-slope-fields). See also [How to visualize slope fields...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/how-to-visualize-slope-fields-of-differential-equations-without-vectors) and [Streamplot for bifurcation diagram](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43155/streamplot-for-bifurcation-diagram/43174#43174).

Comment: Additionally, note that (1200e^(kx))/ (c + e^(kx)) differs from 1200 e^kx/c + e^kx