# Plotting DSolve solution on Vector Field

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, homework

I created a Vector Field for the given problem:[image]
[image]

Then I solved the problem with certain parameters using the DSolve command, receiving this solution: [image]

I want to know how I can plot this solution on my vector plot?
[image]

Can anyone with any experience with Mathematica just help me out, rather than marking this question as a duplicate, I have looked through the site trying to find a similar example and none of them seem to be differential equations and plotting the exact solution on vector plots. This assignment is due at 11 and would really appreciate someone just pointing me in the right direction.
Thanks.

Comment: I checked the link out for the link to the duplicate question, it didn't help me solve my problem, please check my edit.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/mathematica-slope-fields/4614#4614 and the use of `StreamPoints`.

Comment: The question doesn't clearly state what the problem is. Without actual copyable code (minimum working example) and a clear statement of what you're having difficulty with, we have to put in too much guesswork. For example, what is part c? What parameters for the `DSolve` command did you use? Just pasting screen shots is not enough information.

Comment: @Jens I thought it was clear that part C was the solution I posted y(4), which happens to be directly above the problem. And I specifically stated "I want to know how I can plot this SOLUTION on my vector plot." I'd appreciate it if you would actually read questions and try to help rather than being quick to judge and mark as duplicate or bad question.

Comment: The answer then is to add `Epilog -> Point[{4, 3.05}]` to whatever code you used to make the streamline plot. You should also have included that code (assuming the axes in the plot are `x` and `y`, which is also not clear).