# Solution of numerical vector equation

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose I have a vector equation:

```
Y'[t]==rhs[Y[t]]
```

and

```
Y[0]==ConstantArray[0,n]
```

where "rhs[Y[t]]" is a black box function which numerically calculates a N-length vector given  a N-length vector Y[t].

How can I solve such an equation in "NDSolve" ?

Update: Say my rhs is :

```
rhs[{x_?NumberQ,y_?NumberQ]={x,y}
```

Comment: An example of exactly this kind of equation is in my answer to ["I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/769/245). The equation for a field line is exactly of the type you mention. If you need more details on what I did there, let me know.

Comment: Many Thanks. It would be great if you let me know more. Let me tell you what I am not looking for,

Comment: I just added an answer with the relevant parts of my earlier link, applied to a simple example `rhs`. The added ingredient here is to use `Array` to generate the vectors.

Comment: Sorry that I did not make my question clear. I want to know if `rhs[Y[t]]` does not have a symbolic form. That is what I meant by "numerically calculates".

Comment: Hello & welcome! If you register for this site you will be able to access more features, for example voting.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [classic example from documentation center](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dekz2-oedih0). I will modify this slightly, to make it more complex.

```
A = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {5, 5}];
```

Now you can actually mix scalar and vector functions - 'NDSolve' will understand it:

```
fs = x /.First[NDSolve[{x'[t] == 1 - Norm[x[t]] A.Sin[x[t]], 
      x[0] == RandomReal[1, 5]}, x, {t, 0, 23}]];
```

Visualize typically:

```
Plot[fs[t], {t, 0, 23}, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
 Frame -> True, FillingStyle -> Opacity[0.05], Filling -> 0]
```

[image]

Or visualize in an interesting way:

```
ParametricPlot3D[ fs[t][[#1 ;; #2]] & @@@ {{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 5}}, {t, 0, 23}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Thick, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  ImageSize -> 450] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest]
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly,

Comment: Many thanks it works.