# System of ODEs specified by large coefficient matrices

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

What is the best way to call `NDSolve` for solving a system of differential equations of the form

```
Am.y'[x] + Bm.y[x]/x + Cm.y[x] == Dv
```

with `y[0] == Ev` in the interval x from 0 to 1.

where y is an n-vector, Am, Bm, and Cm are n x n coefficient matrices, and Dv and Ev are n vectors.  Say with

```
n=100;
Am = RandomReal[1,{n,n}];
Bm = RandomReal[1,{n,n}];
Cm = RandomReal[1,{n,n}];
Dv = RandomReal[1,{n}];
Ev = RandomReal[1,{n}];
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14407/57

Comment: You also need sufficient initial and boundary conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with some small matrices, but it's the same for large ones. The key point is to use the `NDSolve` option `SolveDelayed->True`

Some system matrices:

```
matS = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}};

matD = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1/1000, 0, -(1/1000), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    1,0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/1000), 0, 1/1000, 0, -1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}};

matM = {{1/1000000, -(1/1000000), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-(1/1000000), 1/
          1000000, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

matL = {0, 0, 0, 0, 5 (1/2 + 1/2 Erf[100000 (-(1/1000) + t)]), 0};

sysSize = Length[matS];
tInit = 0.;
tEnd = 0.01;
init = Table[0, {sysSize}];
dinit = LinearSolve[matD, -(matS.init - matL) /. t -> tInit];

if = u /.First /@ NDSolve[{matM.Derivative[2][u][t]+matD.Derivative[1][u][t] + matS.u[t] == matL, u[tInit] == init,Derivative[1][u][tInit]==dinit}, u, {t, tInit, tEnd},SolveDelayed->True]
```

The interpolation function then returns a vector for a time `t`:

```
if[0.001]
(*
{0.00001410474097541479`, 0.000014042475237194534`, 0.`, 0.`, -1.4042475237194535`*^-8, -1.4042475237194532`*^-8}
*)
```

To plot it:

```
Plot[if[t][[2]], {t, tInit, tEnd}]
```

[image]

If your coefficient matrices are functions, then you can use `matD[x]` and make a function like `matD[x_?VectorQ]:=...` or some other appropriate pattern.

[Here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7549/) is an example for larger system matrices.

Answer (score 0):

This system of differential equations has the form:
$$
   x \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left( \hat{A} \cdot \vec{y}(x) \right) + \left( x \hat{C} + \hat{B} \right) \cdot \vec{y}(x) = x \vec{D} \tag{1}
$$
Notice that $x=0$ is the singular point of the system, hence the initial value problem eq.(1) and $\vec{y}(0) = \vec{E}$ is not well defined, because the fundamental system of eq. (1) becomes degenerate at $x=0$.

[Frobenius method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) can be used to construct a series approximation:
$$
     \vec{y}(x) = \vec{E} + \vec{F}_1 x + \vec{F}_2 \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^2\right) 
$$
Substituting back into eq. (1) we discover:
$$
     \hat{A} \cdot \vec{F}_1 x + 2 \hat{A} \cdot \vec{F}_2 \frac{x^2}{2} + \mathcal{o}\left(x^2\right) + \left(\hat{B} \cdot \vec{E}+ x \left( \hat{C} \cdot \vec{E} + \hat{B} \cdot \vec{F}_1 \right) + \frac{x^2}{2} \left(2 \hat{C} \cdot \vec{F}_1 + \hat{B} \cdot \vec{F}_2 \right) + \mathcal{o}\left(x^2\right) \right) = x \vec{D}
$$
Comparing terms we get:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
     \hat{B} \cdot \vec{E} &=& \vec{0} \\   \left(\hat{A} + \hat{B}\right) \cdot \vec{F}_1 + \hat{C} \cdot \vec{E} &=& \vec{D} \\
      \left(2 \hat{A} + \hat{B}\right) \cdot \vec{F}_2 + 2 \hat{C} \cdot \vec{F}_1 &=& \vec{0}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Assuming consistency and solvability of the above, we can approximate $y(x)$ away from the origin $x=0$, and then call `NDSolve` to solve a well-defined initial value problem.