# Plot with different colors the results of an NDSolve with vector solution

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, interpolation, plot-themes

Consider the following toy example:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == {-1, -2} x[t],
    x[0] == {2, 2}
    },
   x, {t, 0, 4}
   ];
Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

As seen above, both plots are drawn in the same colour.

The usual trick of adding `Evaluate` does not work here, I guess because `x[t] /. sol` evaluates to a list with a single element:

[image]

and it's the `InterpolatingFunction` that later evaluates to a list.

Manually specifying the `PlotStyle` also doesn't seem to work.

*How can I ensure that the different plots are assigned different colours/styles?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed):

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
    {x'[t] == {-1, -2} x[t], x[0] == {2, 2}},
    x,
    {t, 0, 4}
];

Plot[Evaluate @ Table[Indexed[sol[t], i], {i,2}], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I just found that this is covered in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134223/27539), which I previously missed.

The trick is to use `ListLinePlot`, which seems handle `InterpolatingFunction`s better:

```
sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == {-1, -2} x[t],
    x[0] == {2, 2}
    },
   x, {t, 0, 4}
   ];
ListLinePlot[x /. First@sol // Flatten]
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If `Plot` is necessary, the only solution in my mind is rebuilding the `InterpolatingFunction`. I've modified the definition of ODE a bit because `x'[t] == {-1, -2} x[t]` is not valid in *v9.0.1*.

```
Clear@times;
times[a_, b_?VectorQ] := a b
(* Alternatively: *)
(*
times = Compile[{{a, _Real, 1}, {b, _Real, 1}}, a b, 
  RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False]
 *)

sol = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == {-1, -2}~times~x[t], x[0] == {2, 2}}, x, {t, 0, 4}]

sollst = ListInterpolation[#, sol[Coordinates][[1]]] & /@ Transpose@sol[ValuesOnGrid]

Plot[sollst[t] // Through // Evaluate, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

OK, I happened to recall another solution. We can modify the `Graphics` instead:

```
i = 1;
Plot[sol[t], {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[a_] :> Sequence[ColorData[1][i++], Line@a]
```

But this solution is somewhat hard to control if you need deeper customization for the style.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear[sol]

sol[t_] = 
  x[t] /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == {-1, -2} x[t], x[0] == {2, 2}}, 
     x, {t, 0, 4}][[1]];

Plot[{sol[t][[1]], sol[t][[2]]}, {t, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.5, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

Comment: What if the number of elements of the solution array is not known a priori? Replacing the first argument of plot with something like `sol[t][[#]]&/@Range@10` does not work, while `Evaluate[sol[t][[#]]&/@Range@10]` throws an error because `tmp[t]` is not a list when `t` is unevaluated

Comment: ok I think I found the solution to that, leveraging the fact that `Plot` can handle held arguments: something like `Evaluate[Hold[tmp[t][[#]]] & /@ Range@10]` works

Comment: @glS - If the number of elements is not unknown a priori then you would need to calculate the `Range` argument on the fly, i.e., `Evaluate[Hold[sol[t][[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@sol[1]]`