# NDSolve with vector function

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, vector, physics

(Possible [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/ndsolve-with-vectors) yet I still can't understand.)

Basic 2D revolving around origin:

```
With[{o = 2, R = 2},
 NDSolveValue[{
   r''[t] == -o^2 R Normalize[r[t]],
   r[0] == {R, 0},
   r'[0] == {0, o R}},
  r, {t, 0, 3}]]

ParametricPlot[%[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image]

However, I add an origin displacement to *rhs* of `r''[t]` and suddenly it can't be solved.

```
With[{o = 2, R = 2, p = {0, 0}},
 NDSolveValue[{
   r''[t] == -o^2 R Evaluate[Normalize[r[t] - p]],
   r[0] == p + {R, 0},
   r'[0] == {0, o R}},
  r, {t, 0, 3}]]
```

Errors-filled return of `NDSolveValue` also shows *rhs* of `r''[t]` is evaluated in an undesired fashion. How can I remedy this but still go on with my vector variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `Mathematica` prematurely threads `r[t] - p` not knowing `r[t]` is actually in $\mathbb{R}^2$

```
In[]:= r[t] - {0, 0}
Out[]= {r[t], r[t]}
```

Which is not what you want. A quick fix for these types of issues is to create a function that only evaluates for numerical values (Changed to `NDSolve` since I only have version 8):

```
dummy[r_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &), p_] := Normalize[r - p]
With[{o = 2, R = 2, p = {0, 0}},
 NDSolve[
  {r''[t] == -o^2 R dummy[r[t], p], r[0] == p + {R, 0}, r'[0] == {0, o R}},
  r, {t, 0, 3}]
]
```

Where `r_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)` makes sure that the first argument is a list of numbers:

```
In[]:= dummy[r[t], {0, 0}]
Out[]= dummy[r[t], {0, 0}]

In[]:= dummy[{1., 3.}, {0, 0}]
Out[]= {0.316228, 0.948683}
```

This ensures that the evaluation of `Normalize[r[t] - p]` only happens once the solving actually starts, thereby preventing improper threading.

Answer (score 4):

Another useful method for this case is to instead use `TranslationTransform[]`, which sidesteps the premature threading observed in the OP:

```
With[{o = 2, R = 2, p = {0, 0}}, 
     rf = NDSolveValue[{r''[t] == -o^2 R Normalize[TranslationTransform[-p][r[t]]], 
                        r[0] == p + {R, 0}, r'[0] == {0, o R}}, r, {t, 0, 3}]];

ParametricPlot[rf[t], {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: plot of solution]