# Inverting a Spline-Function (Bezier or BSpline)

Tags: equation-solving, splines

I would like to use a Spline-Function to describe a transformation from one range of reals to another, that is I would like to have a function which maps a value $y$ on $x$ and for simplicity let us assume that $x,y \in [0,1]$.

The idea was to define a smooth, nonlinear function which is to be within the boundary points $\{(0,0),(\alpha,\beta),(1,1)\}$ with $\alpha,\beta \in [0,1]$, also. Thus a Bezier- or BSpline-Function seemed to be appropriate.

Unfortunately I can't see how I can use the Spline-Function directly to map $y$ on $x$ (or vice versa for that). The Spline-Function will one parameter $t$ with $t \in [0,1]$ and will give all points on the curve, e.g. $spline(0) = (0,0), spline(1) = (1,1)$.

So to find say the corresponding $x$ value for $y=0.6$, I tried something like this:

```
f = BSplineFunction[{{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}, {1, 1}}];
FindInstance[Last@f[t]==0.6,t]
```

But what I am getting is the false answer $\{\{t\rightarrow 0.6 \}\}$. The correct answer should have been $t = 0.5$.

So far I have also tried Reduce, Solve, NSolve, FindRoot (giving a start value for t) and have of course given the domain to be Reals. But nothing works.

Is there a way to do this without having to substitute a simpler function for the Spline-Function (e.g. using `Interpolation[]`)?

Comment: `Interpolation[ ]`?

Comment: Thank you, Sjoerd, I should have mentioned that solution - whiich is what I am doing now:  using a grid with `Interpolation[]` where I have gotten the best results using `InterpolationOrder->2`. But that still is not perfect and still wonder why equation solving won't work here.

Comment: @gwr Why do you expect `t -> .72` since `f[.5]` gives `y -> .6` in this case?

Comment: @BoLe Uups, you are right, I should have used `Last` instead of `First` in my post here and so you are correct. But that still does not change the principle problem with equation solving. Thanks for pointing out the error, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inverse of your function sampled and interpolated:

```
g = InverseFunction@Interpolation[f /@ Range[0, 1, .1]]

(* gives x for y = .6 *)
g[.6]
    0.35
```

**Using `FindRoot`:**

```
FindRoot[second[f[t]] == .6, {t, .5}]    
    {t -> 0.5}

f[.5]    
    {0.35, 0.6}
```

Delaying evaluation:

```
second[r_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := r[[2]]
```

More general delay:

```
delay[f_, r_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := f[r]

FindRoot[delay[First, f[t]] == .6, {t, .2}]
    {t -> 0.720759}
```

I can't understand why `BSplineFunction` generates a message (`Quiet` for quieting that) but the result is correct, right?

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but I was aware of this possibility already and have accordingly changed my question. Why does "regular" equation solving with the Spline Function not work?

Comment: `FindRoot` can solve this.

Comment: I tried `FindRoot` (e.g. `FindRoot[First@f[t]==0.6,{t,0.5}]`) but I still get the wrong result doing so?

Comment: `First`, `Last`, I don't know which is `x` and which  `y` in this case. :) Anyway, delayed `FindRoot` works. You may want to `Quiet` it here though.

Comment: That is interesting and a bit weird at the same time. I had tried defining a pure function (e.g. `g = Last[#]&`) and then using `Composition[g,f][t]` in the equation definition but that did not work out. I am not quite getting why the delayed function does help here?

Comment: It's a special delay. It waits until `f[t]` evaluates to a list of numbers. (I learnt this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25287/6555).)

Comment: I just tested the `FindRoot`-Solution vs. using `InverseFunction`on an interpolated Function as suggested in the solution on 10000 random values. It surprised me quite a bit to find the FindRoot-solution turning out faster (4.7 secs vs. 6.9 secs).

Comment: For completeness:  Surprisingly using `InverseFunction` with an `InterpolatedFunction` turns out to be slower than the indicated `FindRoot`- solution. But since there should be some symmetry here, I simply switched the $(x,y)$ pairs for the reference points to be $(y,x)$ pairs before letting `Interpolation` with Order 2 and Spline-Method find a solution. Using the thus obtained `InterpolationFunction` is as fast as can be wished for.

Answer (score 3):

If you absolutely must use B-splines, you can explicitly build the component functions that make up the B-spline, using the usual definitions:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {0.2, 0.7}, {1, 1}};

n = Min[Length[pts] - 1, 3]; (* B-spline degree *)
m = Length[pts];
(* clamped uniform knots for B-spline *)
knots = {ConstantArray[0, n + 1], Range[m - n - 1]/(m - n),
         ConstantArray[1, n + 1]} // Flatten;

{xu, yu} = Transpose[pts];
bs = BSplineFunction[pts];

(* B-spline component functions *)

f[t_] = xu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
g[t_] = yu.Table[BSplineBasis[{n, knots}, i - 1, t], {i, Length[pts]}];
```

Now, you can do this:

```
tval = t /. First @ FindRoot[g[t] == 0.6, {t, 0.6, 0, 1}]
   0.5

bs[tval]
   {0.35, 0.6}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. You said "if you absolutely must use B-splines" -- well I need to 'calibrate' a transformation where I do not know the mapping (function) to use. From some reasonable assumptions (all values within $[0,\infty($, the function probably not beeing s-shaped etc., I found a spline to be the best way to define a smooth function with just two parameters (next to one for scaling the maximum value). What else to use/do?

Comment: I would, as Sjoerd and BoLe suggested, just have used `Interpolation[]` to begin with.

Comment: My problem is, that besides the point $(\alpha,\beta)$ where both parameters are to be estimated, and the points $(0,0)$ and $(x_\text{max},y_\text{max})$ I do not know anything else. `Interpolation[]` will give a function passing _through_ the points. I find it very hard to keep it within plausible ranges?

Comment: Interesting... I'll have to think about it.

Comment: Another approach you might want to consider would be to use (say) `NonlinearModelFit` -- this way you get to control very precisely the form of the function and you can choose it to have a nie shape. As an added bonus, you can perhaps even find an analytical inverse, which greatly simplifies that part of the problem.

Comment: "...you can perhaps even find an analytical inverse..." - if the model is sufficiently simple. That's a big "if".

Comment: There's only three data points! But yes, "perhaps" is a big "if"...

Answer (score 3):

Given the discussion, another approach you might want to consider would be to explicitly parameterize a function -- -- this way you get to control very precisely the form of the function and you can choose it to have a nice shape. As an added bonus, you can perhaps even find an analytical inverse, which greatly simplifies that part of the problem. For example, you might do something like:

```
Clear[f,g]
f = NonlinearModelFit[{{0, 0}, {0.2`, 0.7`}, {1, 1}}, b x + a x^(1/3), {a, b}, x]
```

You can plot this the normal way

```
g[x_] := Normal[f]; Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

And of course the inverse can then be found (if the function is sufficiently simple, as this one is) using

```
Solve[y == g[x], x]
```

Probably you can think of a better functional form for your data.

Comment: That is a reasonable suggestion but since I am a bit "clueless" about which functional form to use - and what the implication of it would be - I thought _"that is exactly what splines were invented for"_?

Comment: Well, splines are just one particular polynomial/functional form. They certainly are convenient, and fast, but you only have 3 points, so simplicity and speed are not all that important. Plus getting a closed form answer for the inverse would seem to me to be a significant improvement.