# Introduction to Vectors and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, vector, physics

I want to use NDSolve for a complicated equation that contains vectors. I am still new to Mathematica, and have really enjoyed what I have learned thus far.  Concerning this question, I have already studied and tested a few examples [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14407/ndsolve-with-vectors), and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25260/ndsolve-with-vector-function), but am still unable to grasp some portion of the proper nomenclature solve my equation using vectors in Mathematica.  As an example, this is the [Bloch Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_equations):

$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{M}}{\partial t}=\gamma\left[\mathbf{M} \times \mathbf{B}\right] $$

Here, $\mathbf{M}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ are vectors in Cartesian coordinates,  $\mathbf{B}=B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k}$ and $\mathbf{M}=M_x\hat{i}+M_y\hat{j}+M_z\hat{k}$.

I worked out a simple example, without vectors, with $\mathbf{B}=\hat{k}$:

```
eqn = {mx'[t] == my[t], my'[t] == -mx[t], my[0] == 1, mx[0] == 0}
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {mx[t], my[t]}, {t, 0, 20}]
mxx[t_] = mx[t] /. sol1[[1]];
myy[t_] = my[t] /. sol1[[1]];
ParametricPlot[{mxx[t], myy[t]}, {t, 0, totaltime}]
```

And this works just fine, but I have Mathematica 9.0.1, so I should be able to do it with vectors without performing the cross product by hand and entering it in. So here I take a shot at it:

```
H[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};
eqn = {m'[t] == Cross[m[t], H[0, 0, 1]], m[0] == {1, 0, 0}}
sol1 = NDSolve[eqn, {m[t]}, {t, 0, 10}]
mm[t] = m[t] /. sol1[[1]];
Length[mm[t]]
```

But for the life of me, can't figure out what to do next. I have tried to plot this in a bunch of ways, but nothing seems to give me anything.  The Length of my vector is just one.  I am uncertain if I am using vectors in NDSolve wrong, or something else?

Comment: Try defining `mm` this way: `mm[t_] = m[t] /. sol1[[1]]` and compare `mm[t]` with `mm[0]`.  (An `InterpolatingFunction` evaluates only on a numeric input.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example using vector notation:

```
s = NDSolve[{m'[t] == Cross[m[t], {0, 0, 1}], m[0] == {0, 1, 0}},  m, {t, 0, 1}]
Plot[Evaluate[m[t] /. s], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
s = NDSolve[{m'[t] == Cross[m[t], {Cos@t, Sin@t, 1}], m[0] == {1, 1, 0}}, m, {t, 0, 10}];
ParametricPlot3D[m[t] /. s, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, this and the hundreds of other comments I've been reading in the past few weeks helped me understand this useful software.

Comment: For the 2-D Plot above, how can I plot just the one direction vs time? For the example above, it would be $M_x(t)$, a sin wave. I can do it for a list, but is it possible for the interpolating function?

Comment: @axsvl77 You mean the trajectory? `tray2D[t_] := m[t] /. s[[1]] // Most; ParametricPlot[tray2D[t], {t, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks! Then `tray1D[t_] := m[t]/.s[[1]] // First` to get just one D.

Comment: @axsvl77 Yep, that's it