# Using NDSolve to find particle trajectory

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics

I'm trying to simulate a particle in an electric and magnetic fields, but numerically instead of analytically. This is basically solving the equation

$$q \cdot \left(p'\times B\right) + q\cdot E = m p'',$$

where $p(t)$ is the position in $(x,y,z)$ coordinates.

After viewing a few topics on this site, I've got a good idea on how to get the solution using `NDSolve`, but my program gets stuck, and doesn't come up with anything.

```
b = {1, 0, 0};
e = {0, 0, 1};
q = 1;
m = 1;

sol = NDSolve[ {q*e + q*Cross[D[pos[t], t], b] == m D[pos[t], {t, 2}],
     pos[0] == {0, 0, 0}, (D[pos[t], t] /. t -> 0) == {0, 0, 0}}, 
   pos, {t, 0, 1}];
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[pos[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 1}];
```

It is also worth mentioning that if you remove the $q\cdot E$ term, the calculation is finished, but nothing shows up in the plot.

Comment: I haven't worked with vectors in Mathematica so I may not be able to help with that.  However, your ParametricPlot3D has incorrect syntax.  Assuming that `pos` is the position, is your initial acceleration zero?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The main problem is that your `pos` is not seen as a 3D vector.

The cross product is therefore interpreted as a scalar:

```
q*Cross[D[pos[t], t], b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

when adding this to the vector q.e this 'scalar' term is added to each of the vector components:

```
q*e + q*Cross[D[pos[t], t], b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This won't work, instead do:

```
b = {1, 0, 0};
e = {0, 0, 1};
q = 1;
m = 1;
```

Define `pos` as a 3D vector. Also take more time than a single second:

```
ClearAll[pos]
pos[t_] = {px[t], py[t], pz[t]};
sol = NDSolve[
  {
   q*e + q*Cross[D[pos[t], t], b] == m D[pos[t], {t, 2}],
   pos[0] == {0, 0, 0},
   (D[pos[t], t] /. t -> 0) == {0, 0, 0}
   }, pos[t], {t, 0, 20}]

ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[pos[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: what is the difference with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/67416/204).  In the latter answer, the author did not have to make `m` a 3D vector.  In the current problem, is it the addition of `q*E` that leads to two matrices that may not be "added" together?

Comment: @drN Good point. I elaborated the answer somewhat.

Answer (score 8):

Alternative method:

```
b = {1, 0, 0};
e = {0, 0, 1};
q = 1;
m = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{e + Cross[pos'[t], b] == m/q pos''[t], 
    pos[0] == {0, 0, 0}, pos'[0] == {0, 0, 0}}, pos, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}];
ParametricPlot3D[pos[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: `EquationSimplification->"Residual"` is magic?

Comment: @drN It's a bit of a mystery, isn't it, since the LHS of the `pos''[t]` evaluates to 3x3 matrix and the RHS is a 3-vector.  But it works, I guess: Look at the diagonal of the matrix in `Inactivate[{e + Cross[pos'[t], b] == m/q pos''[t], pos[0] == {0, 0, 0}, pos'[0] == {0, 0, 0}}, Equal] /. sol /. t -> 1`.  It probably minimizes the norm of the residual (the matrix minus the vector), which in this case would lead to the correct solution, but if so, you'd think the large norm would cause an error/warning.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to package your constant vector parameters as [`DiscreteVariables`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteVariables.html). In the OP's case, it necessary only to chnage `e` since `b` occurs inside `Cross`, which will not evaluate until all its arguments are vectors. Note that in the equation we changed `e` to `e[t]` and set its value with `e[0] == {0, 0, 1}`.

```
b = {1, 0, 0};
(*e={0,0,1};*)
q = 1;
m = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{q*e[t] + q*Cross[D[pos[t], t], b] == m D[pos[t], {t, 2}], 
    pos[0] == {0, 0, 0}, (D[pos[t], t] /. t -> 0) == {0, 0, 0}, 
    e[0] == {0, 0, 1}}, pos, {t, 0, 10}, DiscreteVariables -> {e}];

ParametricPlot3D[pos[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]