# 3d phase portrait for a system of DEs

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a phase portrait for a system of three differential equations
so could anybody help?
example for :

```
          x'[t]=y[t]+x[t]
          y'[t]=y[t]z[t]+x[t]
          z'[t]=z[t]-x[t]-y[t]
```

I've tried using `PhasePlot[]` (package [here](http://users.dimi.uniud.it/~gianluca.gorni/Mma/Mma.html)) and `ParametricPlot3D[]` but couldn't  achieve anything

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: It seems that your system diverges, that is, all trajectories run away.

Comment: that system was just an example 
but i don't know how to plot a phase portrait for a given system od 3 ODEs so that's why i need help(i'm quite new to mathematica)

Comment: `StreamPlot` handles 2D systems only (`PhasePlot` is not a *Mathematica* function).  `VectorPlot3D` can plot the phase field.  You will have to write your own function for plotting the phase curves (or find someone else's, if you can).  (E.g., `VectorPlot3D[{y[t] + x[t], y[t] z[t] + x[t], z[t] - x[t] - y[t]} /. v_[t] :> v, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`.)

Comment: i found PhasePlot in a package called CurvesGraphics6 but i don't know how to use the solutions of the given system for plotting or how to plot trajectories

Comment: With three variables wouldn't the phase space be 6 dimensional? How do you propose to visualize that?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries In the terminology of the linked package, phase plot just means a portrait of the flow in real space.

Comment: @jens OK, didn't examine the package. Is that standard terminology?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yes, it's standard terminology in differential equations.

Comment: @jens I seem to remember that phase plots were velocity against position.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Terminology always depends on the context of the field. What you mean is a *phase-space* portrait.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I get using my answer to [I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/769/245). You only have to copy the definitions from the first code block in that answer, and then enter this:

```
seedList = 
  With[{vertices = .1 N[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"][[1, 1]]]}, 
   Join[Map[{#, 2} &, vertices], 
    Map[{# + {1, 1, 1}, -2} &, vertices]]];

Show[fieldLinePlot[{y + x, y z + x, z - x - y}, {x, y, z}, seedList, 
  PlotStyle -> {Orange, Specularity[White, 16], Tube[.01]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None], 
 Background -> Black]
```

[image: field]

The seed points in `seedList` can be adjusted to highlight different features, if desired.