# StreamPlot in 3 Dimensions

Tags: vector, streams

I would like to plot the vector equation $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{{ - a + \sqrt {{a^2} + 4bc} }}{c}}\\
{\frac{{ - a - \sqrt {{a^2} + 4bc} }}{c}}\\
1
\end{array}} \right)$ as a stream plot in 3 dimensions for the values $a \in (0,1)$, $b,c \in (-5,5)$. How would I do this?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/687/id-like-to-display-field-lines-for-a-point-charge-in-3-dimensions looks like a similar question.

Comment: Not quite ideal for my purposes. When I input the generating function for the seed, it crashes.

Comment: VectorPlot3D     may help you to achieve the goal. Though it has different meaning.