# Continuously varying tube radius

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm currently trying to draw tubular neighborhoods of torus knots, which *Mathematica*'s `Tube` function allows me to do quite easily.  My question regards the appearance of the neighborhood: is there any way to use an explicit function to continuously specify the radius of the tube?  I've managed to find a few examples with nonconstant radii, but nothing where it varies continuously.

I did manage to find enough examples to figure out how draw these tubular neighborhoods so that they are colored according to an explicit function.  If possible, I would like the radius to correspond to the color at every point on the curve.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
Clear[γ, t, w, wColor, wmin, wmax]

(*Define a torus knot γ and a weight function w*)
γ[t_] = {(2 + Cos[3 t]) Cos[2 t], (2 + Cos[3 t]) Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]};
w[t_] = 2 + Cos[t];

(*All this nonsense makes red the heaviest and blue the lightest*)
wmin = First[FindMinimum[{w[t], 0 <= t <= 2 π}, {t, .1}]];
wmax = First[FindMaximum[{w[t], 0 <= t <= 2 π}, {t, .1}]];
wColor[t_] = (7/10)*(1 - ((w[t] - wmin)/(wmax - wmin)));

ParametricPlot3D[γ[t], {t, 0, 2 π + .01}, 
   ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[wColor[t]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], CapForm[None]], 
   PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   Axes -> None, 
   Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}] /. 
   Line[pts_, rest___] -> Tube[pts, 0.2, rest]
```

In short, I would like to continuously vary the radius of this tube:

[image: colored tube]

Comment: I did something like that [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/769/245).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can take a continuous function and evaluate it at the same points that are also used by `ParametricPlot3D` to create the curve. Here is a way to do it:

```
rr = Reap[
   ParametricPlot3D[γ[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi + .01}, 
    ColorFunction -> 
     Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[wColor[Sow[t, "tValues"]]]], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.7], CapForm[None]], 
    PlotRange -> All, Boxed -> False, MaxRecursion -> 0, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, Axes -> None, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 30}], 
   "tValues"];
rr[[1]] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.2 + .1 Sin[rr[[2]]], rest]
```

[image: plot]

Here I chose a `Sin[t]` variation of the thickness. To do it, I collect the evaluation points from inside `ParametricPlot3D` using [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

This list of points is in `rr[[2]]`, whereas `rr[[1]]` is the plot itself. Then I modify the replacement rule you already had by making the radii of `Tube` into a list obtained by applying the desired continuous function to `rr[[2]]`.

Comment: Again, thank you so much for helping me with this.  It has had a tremendous impact on my ability to communicate my research effectively.

Comment: @AegisCruiser Glad to hear it. Looking at my solution, it's better to use `:>` (`RuleDelayed`) instead of `->` in the last step where `tube` is introduced. It won't matter as long as `pts` and `rest` are undefined globally, but `:>` insures that things won't break even if `pts` has a value before it is used as the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility for making a tube with continuously varying width from a space curve is to compute the normal and binormal vectors of the curve with `FrenetSerretSystem[]`, which can then be used to assemble the parametric equations of the tube surface. (In general this can fail, but it will work for torus knots).

```
γ[t_] := {(2 + Cos[3 t]) Cos[2 t], (2 + Cos[3 t]) Sin[2 t], Sin[3 t]};
w[t_] := 2 + Cos[t];

(* normal and binormal vectors *)
{no[t_], bi[t_]} = FrenetSerretSystem[γ[t], t][[-1, {2, 3}]];

ParametricPlot3D[γ[t] + (w[π/2 - t]/10) {Cos[u], Sin[u]}.{no[t], bi[t]},
                 {t, 0, 2 π}, {u, 0, 2 π}, Axes -> None, Boxed -> False, 
                 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[1 - w[t]/3, 1, 1, 0.7]], 
                 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> False, PlotPoints -> {85, 20},
                 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: colored torus knot with varying radius]

(Note how I incorporated the opacity information as the fourth parameter in `Hue[]`.)

If one finds the Frenet-Serret computations to be too slow, one can use e.g. Bishop frames (see e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167614) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169836)) instead, but I will not be discussing them further here.

Comment: `Simplify`  the expression `{no[t_], bi[t_]}` make the plot faster.