# Rendering realistically looking rope

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, rendering

I used [this code of user Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167614/53172) to try render a realistic looking rope. The result using `ParametricPlot3D` is here:
[image]

In fact not very realistic. The trefoil knot is wrapped with 4 helix tubes.

1. How to achieve a better result?
2. Is it possible to use only one tube with some texture on it or one tube with non-circle cross section?

I do not even know if it is possible to have `Tube` for example with a triangle cross section. Is it?

And another thing... if you look at the picture carefully you will see a grain noise on it. I used parameters `PlotPoints -> 300`, `PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"` but there were no difference. If I used only one helix, than there were no grain noise. What causes this noise?

**EDIT 1**:

I just added `PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.99]]` (for a placebo effect ;-)) to `ParametricPlot3D` and the grain noise disappeared. So I think it is a bug in Mathematica.

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

The code

```
(*Trefoil knot parametric equations*)
\[Gamma]=t\[Function]{Sin[2 \[Pi] t]+ 2 Sin[2 2 \[Pi] t],Cos[2 \[Pi] t]-2 Cos[2 2 \[Pi] t],-Sin[3 2 \[Pi] t]};

a=0;b=1;
\[Omega]=10;
r=0.4;
(*unit tangent vector*)T=t\[Function]Evaluate[\[Gamma]'[t]/Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]]];
(*curvature vector*)\[Kappa]=t\[Function]Evaluate[T'[t]/Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]]];
(*compute Bishop frame*)u0=Automatic;
If[!VectorQ[u0],u0=IdentityMatrix[3][[Ordering[Abs[\[Gamma]'[0]],1][[1]]]];]
A=t\[Function]Evaluate[Array[ToExpression["a"<>ToString[#1]<>ToString[#2]][t]&,{3,3}]];
sol=NDSolve[Evaluate@Thread[Flatten[{A'[t][[1]]-Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]] (A[t][[2]] A[t][[2]].\[Kappa][t]+A[t][[3]] A[t][[3]].\[Kappa][t]),A'[t][[2]]+Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]] (A[t][[1]] A[t][[2]].\[Kappa][t]),A'[t][[3]]+Sqrt[\[Gamma]'[t].\[Gamma]'[t]] (A[t][[1]] A[t][[3]].\[Kappa][t]),A[0]-Orthogonalize[{T[0],u0,Cross[T[0],u0]}]}]==0],Evaluate[Flatten[A[t]]],{t,a,b},InterpolationOrder->All][[1]]//Quiet;
frame=t\[Function]Evaluate[A[t]/.sol];
If[(Norm[\[Gamma][a]-\[Gamma][b]]<10^-8)&&(Norm[\[Gamma]'[a]-\[Gamma]'[b]]<10^-8),\[Omega]-=ArcTan@@LinearSolve[Transpose[frame[b]],Transpose[frame[a]]][[2,2;;3]]/(b-a)/(2 Pi);];
frame1=t\[Function]{frame[t][[1]],frame[t][[2]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t]+frame[t][[3]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t],-frame[t][[2]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t]+frame[t][[3]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t]};
frame2=t\[Function]{frame[t][[1]],frame[t][[2]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+2\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+2\[Pi]/4],-frame[t][[2]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+2\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+2\[Pi]/4]};
frame3=t\[Function]{frame[t][[1]],frame[t][[2]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+4\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+4\[Pi]/4],-frame[t][[2]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+4\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+4\[Pi]/4]};
frame4=t\[Function]{frame[t][[1]],frame[t][[2]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+6\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+6\[Pi]/4],-frame[t][[2]] Sin[2 Pi \[Omega] t+6\[Pi]/4]+frame[t][[3]] Cos[2 Pi \[Omega] t+6\[Pi]/4]};
\[Delta]1=t\[Function]\[Gamma][t]+r frame1[t][[2]];
\[Delta]2=t\[Function]\[Gamma][t]+r frame2[t][[2]];
\[Delta]3=t\[Function]\[Gamma][t]+r frame3[t][[2]];
\[Delta]4=t\[Function]\[Gamma][t]+r frame4[t][[2]];
ParametricPlot3D[{\[Gamma][t],\[Delta]1[t],\[Delta]2[t],\[Delta]3[t],\[Delta]4[t]},{t,a,b},SphericalRegion->True,PlotPoints->300,PerformanceGoal->"Quality",PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.99]],Boxed->False,Axes->False]/.Line[pts_,rest___]:>Tube[pts,0.25,rest]
```

**EDIT 3**:

How to achieve for example this? Only one textured tube, no computationally intensive wrapping with helices needed. The image downloaded form https://www.pngwave.com.

[image]

**EDIT 4**:

If you cannot see the noise on the first image here is the same plot magnified inside Mathematica to see the noise. To reproduce just use my code without `PlotStyle->Directive[Opacity[0.99]]`.

[image]

Comment: Would you please share the precise code that you used to generate the plots? Computing `VertexNormals` should resolve the problem, but it has to be done manually.

Comment: It is basically your code... just slight adjustments and using `ParametricPlot3D` instead of `Graphics3D`. Concerning the `VertexNormals` what problem you want to resolve? The grain noise? It is only secondary problem for me, as `Opacity[0.99]` resolved the problem for me. I am more interested in other ways how to achieve more realistically looking rope. I will add the code to my question.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: How to copy code from mathematica that when pasted it will give me nice `ω` instead of cumbersome `\[Omega]`?

Comment: Do you have the [editor buttons](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons) installed?  It allows you to replace symbols with something more readable.

Comment: Your "EDIT 2" looks like you forgot the code?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "grain noise."  I see no difference between the two images.

Comment: You do not see any difference between the two images??? Look closely to the first image there are random pixel of other color than they should be. Like on an old photographic film - and it is called film grain - signal-dependent noise.

Comment: @Tim Laska: Thanks for tip but I am not going to install it. If it is possible to have nice `ω` instead of `\[Omega]` on this site than it is problem of this site that it can not interpret it nicely. I will post the code as it is.

Comment: @MichaelE2 It took me a long time to see it, but I do see some graininess in the first picture on the underside of the yellow and green tubes at the very top of the knot.

Comment: Yes that's it. I depends how big your monitor is. Maybe on smaller ones you can not notice it at first sight. There is some grain also on the left of the middle part and also left of the bottom right part. But as I said it is only secondary problem for me as `Opacity` resolved it for me. There is no grain on the second image.

Comment: @Michael E2: I uploaded magnified image to see the noise more easily.

Comment: Ah, you have used the `Tube` primitive. Then nothing can be done about it. That is why I wrote my own routines for things like tubes that produce quadrilateral or triangle meshes in the form of `GraphicsComplex`es. You can map textures onto those with `Graphics3D[ { Texture[<<img>>], GraphicsComplex[ <<points>>, Polygon[ << faces>> ], VertexNormals -> <<vertex normals>>, VertexTextureCoordinates -> <<u-v-Coordinates of each vertex between 0 and 1, relative to the image <<img>> >> }]`.