# Tube with variable color, opacity, and radius

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

Well, it's "two out of three ain't bad"...

So far I have this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 25}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[#3/2], Hue[1/2 - 1/5 #3]] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1, rest]
```

[image]

but now I'd like to vary the tube radius, too. Perhaps as a function of one or a combination of coordinates, or a function of the curve length, etc. I can't figure out how to replace that `0.1` I have with some function that achieves what I want.

I also cobbled this together from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104863/continuously-varying-tube-radius), but then I don't know how to vary the opacity the way I want it:

```
rr = Reap[
  ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 25}, 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x, y, z, t}, Hue[Sow[1/2 - t/50, "tValues"]]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], CapForm[Round]], 
   PlotRange -> All, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 300, 
   Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 300}], "tValues"]; 
rr[[1]] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1 - .15 rr[[2]], rest]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code is based on the `Reap`-`Sow` approach, and uses for the `ColorFunction` a pure function, as in your first approach. The pure function is rewritten with `Sow` and uses the slot `#4` for the color variation, rather than `#3`, to take the values given by `u`.

```
rr = Reap[
       ParametricPlot3D[
         {Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 25}, 
          ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[0.5 #3], Hue[Sow[1/2 - #4/50]]] &), 
          ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
          PlotRange -> All,
          MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 300, 
          Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 300}
       ]
];

rr[[1]] /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1 - .15 rr[[2]], rest]
```

[image]

Note that since here $z = u /10$, it is equivalent to use instead:

```
Hue[Sow[1/2 - #3/5]]
```

which is what you have for the `ColorFunction` of your first approach (`Sow` apart).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So, why #4? Is it: #1: x, #2, y, #3, z, #4, t? Where would I find things like that documented? And what are the parts of `rr`?

Comment: The slots are respectively `x`, `y`, `z` and `u` (and possibly `v` if given). This is documented in the section "Details" of `ColorFunction` ref page. `rr[[1]]` is the graph with lines, and `rr[[2]]` is the list generated from `1/2 - #4 /50` at the evaluation points `u`.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is equivalent to Xavier's, except that I use `EvaluationMonitor` to catch the parameter values being used to plot the curve.

```
{plot, vals} = Reap[ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[u], Cos[u], u/10}, {u, 0, 25}, 
                                     ColorFunction -> (Hue[1/2 - #4/50, 1, 1, 0.5 #3] &), 
                                     ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
                                     EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[u], 
                                     MaxRecursion -> 0, Method -> {"TubePoints" -> 300},
                                     PlotPoints -> 300]];

Show[plot /. Line[pts_, rest___] :> Tube[pts, 0.1 - .15 (1/2 - Sort[vals[[1]]]/50), rest],
     PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: some weirdly-colored tube]