# What code can I use to calculate, integrate, and visualize the electric field for an arbitrary shape?

Tags: finite-element-method, simulation

I'm looking for a *Mathematica* program/function with which I'd be able to specify two objects in 3D space, each at a different surface potential, and then the program would calculate (using Finite Element Analysis I assume?) the electric field in the region around them, allow me to integrate that field over some region, and also let me see the field as a vector field or [cool contour plot like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKLih.jpg)

I've searched some and found stuff like [this page of Mathematica demonstrations,](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=electrostatics&start=1&limit=20&sortmethod=recent) but they're all either too specific (just one type of shape) or too simple.

Does anyone know of a more general program that already exists? Thank you!

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, that would be fun answering, but it **is** too broad as written.  If you could include a couple examples, with shapes and corresponding charge distributions, and ask for a function that returned a plot of the field given those inputs, then it could be answered.

Comment: For 3D problems, see also [I'd like to display field lines for a point charge in 3 dimensions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/687/245).

Comment: @jens I've actually managed to solve the problem using jens solution and some other stuff, thank you!

Comment: @YungHummmma Then it is common practice to answer your own question. Share it with us.