# Plotting the Magnetic Field

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, physics

I have a dataset of $ \textbf{B} = {B_x, B_y, B_z}$. (Quite a big dataset :78*100*150)

I want to plot magnetic field lines.

If I was working with an analytical function, the magnetic field line would be defined as

$\frac{dx}{B_x}=\frac{dy}{B_y}=\frac{dz}{B_z}=\frac{ds}{B}$

Where $B=\sqrt{\textbf{B} \cdot \textbf{B}}= B_x^2+B_y^2+B_z^2$. I would then work out an expression for the field by solving the equation, for instance by taking integrals:

$\int B_y dx = \int B_x dy... $

Which would give an expression which evaluates to a constant which I can plot.

For example, I can do this:

```
bx = y[x]/a;
by = x/a ;
bz = 0;

a = 2
bfield = DSolve[Dt[x]/(bx) == Dt[y[x]]/(by), y[x], x]

Plot[Evaluate[
  y[x] /. bfield /. {C[1] -> Table[x, {x, -10, 10, 2}]}], {x, -7, 7}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
Now, I'm not working with an analytical function - I'm working with a datacube. Interpolating it seems like a lot of effort. ListVectorPlot3D doesn't have an option to create field lines. But, how should I plot the magnetic field lines?

Is there anyway I can modify ListVectorPlot3D to have continuous lines which show the strength of the field by how many lines are drawn. Or are there any other functions or good ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately I think interpolation will be necessary. Then you could use the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/687/245). There are also `ListStreamDensityPlot` and `ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot`, but they work only on 2D slices which is inappropriate if your field lines aren't in a plane.

Comment: Is interpolation possible for a vector field? (i.e. with 3 dimensions and a vector at each point). -  asked another question to find out - http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140778/interpolation-of-discrete-3d-vector-field/140786#140786

Comment: Yes it is possible, and I posted another answer at the linked question.