# Interpolation of Discrete 3D Vector Field

Tags: plotting, interpolation, vector

I have a vector field with discrete values and I want to interpolate these values to create a differentiable vector field.

I have matrices which give the vector values of the velocity - $vx, vy, vz$. They have dimensions of $(5,5,5)$. I put these together to get a vector field which looks like $(vx,vy,vz)$ with dimensions $(5,5,5,3)$ i.e. each coordinate has a vector at it.

But the interpolation function on this matrix doesn't seem to work.

```
interpolation = ListInterpolation[together]
```

No errors here, but when I plot it I get a blank graph, whereas from the "raw" data I get what I would expect.

All Code:

```
vx = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5, 5}]
vx = ConstantArray[3, {5, 5, 5}]
vy = ConstantArray[2, {5, 5, 5}]


together = 
 ArrayReshape[Transpose[Flatten /@ {vx, vy, vz}], {5, 5, 5, 3}]

interpolation = ListInterpolation[together]

ListVectorPlot3D[together]
VectorPlot3D[interpolation[x, y, z], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

From ListVectorPlot:

[image]

From VectorPlot3D (interpolation):

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem with a 2D vector field with data of the form: {{x,y},{vx,vy}}, namely the value of teh coordinate {x,y} where I have the vector {vx,vy}. I want to interpolate these values to create a differentiable vector field. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible to get vectorial output from `ListInterpolation`. Here is a way to do it,  given your original data (with typos corrected):

```
vx = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5, 5}];
vy = ConstantArray[3, {5, 5, 5}];
vz = ConstantArray[2, {5, 5, 5}];

together = 
  ArrayReshape[Transpose[Flatten /@ {vx, vy, vz}], {5, 5, 5, 3}];

interpolation = 
  ListInterpolation[Map[{#} &, together, {-2}], {{1, 5}, {1, 5}, {1, 5}}];

VectorPlot3D[interpolation[x, y, z], {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}, {z, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

The result of this plot is the same as for the original field. To provide some additional guidance to `ListInterpolation`, I wrapped each of the vectors in a list using `Map`. Then I also provided the range of indices in the three coordinate directions as arguments to `ListInterpolation`. With this, the output of the interpolation has the correct dimensions:

```
interpolation
```

[image]

The choice of arguments for `ListInterpolation` could of course be automated based on the dimensions of the original data array.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Interpolation only works on scalar values</s>.  So if you want to interpolate a vector field, you might have to interpolate each component individually.  For an example in 2D:

```
vx = ConstantArray[1, {5, 5}]; vx[[3, 3]] = -1;
vy = ConstantArray[2, {5, 5}];

VectorPlot[
  {ListInterpolation[vx][x, y], ListInterpolation[vy][x, y]},
  {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 5}]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Actually, your statement about only scalar interpolation being possible is not correct, although your answer certainly would also work. See my alternative answer that shows it also works vectorially.